# Time Zone Sensitive Date and Time Display in Web Applications?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

**I am looking for recommendations on displaying times in a web application in a time zone other than the user's current time zone.**

We store our dates/times in UTC/GMT in the database, so it is not an issue to format the time for UTC/GMT or the user's current time zone.  However, in other situations we need to display the time from the point of view of an arbitrary time zone (i.e. every date/time on this page is in Eastern, regardless of whether or not the user is in West Coast, Central, Eastern, etc.).

In the past we have stored offsets or time zone info, then done the calculations in server code in .Net or else we have done some client-side manipulations in javascript that I would prefer to avoid, since it all becomes very dependent on javascript and the user's browser.  I'd like to know the best way to do this in a more client-side/MVC type application.

Here is an example:

1. Date stored in db: 1302790667 (Thu, 14 Apr 2011 14:17:47 GMT)
2. Converted date displayed for a client in Central time zone: Thu Apr 14 09:17:47 2011
3. Date I actually want to display, always in Eastern time zone: Thu Apr 14 10:17:47 2011

In the above example, it's easy to get the time in UTC (#1) or the user's current time zone (#2) but it is more difficult to get #3.  My options seem to be:

1. Store offsets or time zones in the db and do calculations on the client - this is what we've done in the past with .Net but it seems even messier in client side code is the path we are currently trying to avoid.
2. Do the conversion on the server and send down a full date for display to the client - client receives a string ("Thu Apr 14 10:17:47 2011").  This works but it's not very flexible.
3. Do the conversion on the server, break it into parts and send those down to the client, then put them back together.  ("{DayOfWeek:Thu, Month:Apr, Day:14, Hour:10, Minute:17}").  This gives us the correct data and gives us more flexibility in formatting the date but it feels a little wrong for this scenario.

Any other options ideas?  How do others handle similar situations?  Thanks.

Comment: What did you end up using?  I'm about to give [this](https://github.com/csnover/js-iso8601) a try, I have the same customer requirement & I'm racing the clock on this one!

Comment: We ended up doing all of the calculations on the server.  I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Our results:

1. I tried out a few libraries like Datejs, MS Ajax, etc. and I was never very happy with them.  Datejs didn't work at all in a few of my test cases, is not actively maintained, and seemed to focus a lot on syntactic sugar that we don't need (date.today().first().thursday(), etc.)
2. We do use jQuery for some basic date/time parsing.
3. I came across a lot of "roll-your-own" client-side date conversion "hacks", most of which only addressed the conversion to UTC, started off working fine, and then eventually fell apart on some edge case.  [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc) was the 90% solution for a lot of standard UTC conversion but didn't solve our "arbitrary timezone" issue.

**Between the code complexity the conversion routines added and the bugs they seemed to cause, we decided to avoid client side date processing most of the time.  We do the date conversions on the server with our existing date handling routines and pass the formatted dates or info down as properties to be used by the view. If we need a separate date, we just add another property.  There are usually only a few properties that we need at a time (i.e. EventDateUTC, EventDateLocal, EventDateAlwaysAustralia, and EventDayOfWeek).**

Answer (score 0):

I offer the suggestion that you look into the [Datejs](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation) library.  It offers a bunch of extensions to basic JavaScript date manipulation, including a "setTimezone()" method and flexible ways to convert a date into a formatted string for display.

I usually hesitate to suggest libraries when their use is not explicitly allowed for in questions, but Datejs isn't very large and it's pretty solid (even though it's called an "alpha" release). If you'd prefer not to rely on something like that, you might want to look at it anyway just to see the basics of how its extensions were implemented.