# Javascript Date to UTC time stamp

Tags: javascript, timestamp, utc

I have UTC: 1325271847. On this I use javascript to convert it to **Fri Dec 30 2011 14:04:07 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)**. I want to convert it back to UTC format. ie 1325253847.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc

Comment: Thanks, Mastermind!. I think i can work it out from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.write(new Date("Fri Dec 30 2011 14:04:07 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)").getTime()/1000 + " seconds since 1970/01/01");
```