# Convert Date and Time into a UTC formatted Date - Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have two variables, date & time...

```
var date = "2012-12-05";
var time = "18:00";
```

How can I format this into a UTC formatted date. This is so I can use it within the Facebook API..

Facebook states I need it in this format:

*Precise-time (e.g., '2012-07-04T19:00:00-0700'): events that start at a particular point in time, in a specific offset from UTC. This is the way new Facebook events keep track of time, and allows users to view events in different timezones.*

Any help would be much appreciated.. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This format is called `ISO 8601`

Do you know what timezone you are in? If you do, you can do like this:

```
var datetime = date + 'T' + time + ":00+0000';
```

if the timezone is +0.
if not, then:

```
var d = new Date()
var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();
var timeZone = Math.floor( Math.abs( n/60 ) );
var timeZoneString = (d.getTimezoneOffset() < 0 ? '-' : '+' ) + ( timeZone < 10 ? '0' + timeZone : timeZone ) + '00';

var datetime = date + 'T' + time + ':00' + timeZoneString;
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ajySr/

Comment: Is there any way to automatically get the timezone?

Comment: There is the `getTimezoneOffset` function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var date = new Date(2012, 12, 5, 18, 0, 0, 0); 
var date_utc = new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(),  date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds());
```

The `Date` function can be used the following ways:

```
var d = new Date();
var d = new Date(milliseconds);
var d = new Date(dateString);
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

This was taken from a related post here: [How do you convert a JavaScript date to UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc)

To find out more, please refer to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date