# javascript date varies across timezone

Tags: javascript

```
var dt_now = '2-22-2013';//mm-dd-yyyy, this is dynamic in actual code
            dt_now = dt_now.split("-");
            dt_now = addZero(dt_now[2])+'-'+addZero(dt_now[0])+'-'+addZero(dt_now[1]);
            dt_now = new Date(dt_now);
```

I am using the above code to convert a user defined text to actual date for use in rest of my code. it seems to work ok for me but on another system which is situated in a different timezone(my time -12 hours), the date comes out as `February 21st` instead of `Feb 22nd`, that is, it is running **one day behind the expected date**. I have no idea how to fix this or what the error might be. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just do everything in _UTC_. For example, use an ISO 8601 Date String `new Date('yyyy-mm-ddT00:00Z')`, the `Z` indicating UTC (timezone +0000)

Comment: and how do I do that exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid timezone issues, use UTC. You don't have to rely on a library; simple ISO 8601 date strings would be sufficient. See [`Date.prototype.toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) for making one from a *Date* ([compatibility](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/)).

Constructing is as simple as `new Date('yyyy-mm-ddT00:00Z')`, so you just need a minor change to your code to create a *Date*

```
var dt_now = '2-22-2013';//mm-dd-yyyy, this is dynamic in actual code
dt_now = dt_now.split("-");
dt_now = addZero(dt_now[2])+'-'+addZero(dt_now[0])+'-'+addZero(dt_now[1])+'T00:00Z';
dt_now = new Date(dt_now);
```

The `Z` indicates *UTC*. I include a time (`T00:00`) so it matches that which would be generated by `toISOString`.

Answer (score 0):

In the method that outputs the date you need to use `getUTC*` instead of `get*`, i.e. `getUTCDate()`. To generate a date object with UTC info refer to the second answer in [How do you convert a JavaScript date to UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc)