# JSon deserialize DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have got a Date returned from an Api as a Json object which looks like this: Date(1371510000000)
When I open internet Explorer and paste the following in the url: javascript:alert(Date(1371510000000))
I get an alert reading the date 19 June 2013 (which is correct).

However when I deserialize this date in .NET using NewtonSoft's Json deserializer as shown below:

```
var x = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>("\"/Date(1371510000000)/\"");
```

It parses the date as 17 June 2013 (which is incorrect).

Is there anything that I am doing incorrectly ?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like an issue with local time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc

Comment: I have inserted the parameter JSonSerializerSettings with my local culture, timezone info but the problem is still there.

Comment: Why do you believe that "19 June 2013" is correct for 1371510000000?  Running your javascript doesn't give the same result each time.  I don't think your javascript is doing what you think.

Comment: Might be very old, but you need to write:
`javascript:alert(new Date(1371510000000))`

Answer (score 0):

The javascript Date object is something that is not serializable by .Net,

what you do is fix the date before you transfer your object:

```
function fixDate(date) {
    if (date != undefined && date != null && date.getDate) {
        var curr_date = date.getDate();
        var curr_month = date.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
        var curr_year = date.getFullYear();
        date = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year;
        date = date.replace(/\b\d\b/g, '0$&');
    }
    return date;
}
```

this code is for the "dd/MM/yyyy" format , but you can format it how ever you like.

remember to choose the specific format in your server as well

Comment: I don't understand why the browser deserializes the same date correctly. Isn't there any way of making .NET do the same ?

Comment: When you run that in the browser it runs the javascript code, .Net doesn't have the same deserializers