# JS get date in UTC time

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I've created a date in JS like so:

```
var myDate = new Date('2013-01-01 00:00:00');
```

I assume JS reads this in as UTC time. But when I do something like myDate.getTime() the timestamp returned was something like 4AM GMT time.

Why is this? And how do I get the date as midnight in UTC time?

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc

Comment: Nice resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate

Comment: Which timezone are you based in?

Comment: I think the issue is, JS is interpreting that date string as EST timezone, where I want it as UTC. I cannot use Date.UTC() because I have a date string, not the day, month, hour, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you convert a JavaScript date to UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc)

Answer (score 2):

At least in Chrome, this works:

`var myDate = new Date('2013-01-01 00:00:00 UTC');`

It also works if you put `GMT` instead of `UTC`. But I don't know if this is cross-browser enough.

Answer (score 2):

I live in India. Hence my timezone is the Indian Standard Time (IST) which is listed in the tz database as `Asia/Kolkata`. India is 5 hours 30 minutes ahead of GMT. Hence when I execute `new Date("2013-01-01 00:00:00")` the actual time at GMT is `"2012-12-31 18:30:00"`.

I believe you live in America because you're in the EST timezone (GMT-04:00)? Am I right?

If you want to parse the time at GMT instead of your local timezone then do this:

```
new Date("2013-01-01T00:00:00+00:00");
```

Notice the capital `T` between the date and the time, and the `+00:00` at the end. This is the format used to parse a given time in a specific timezone.

---

Given the date string `"2013-01-01 00:00:00"` you can convert it to the required format using the following function:

```
function formatDateString(string, timezone) {
    return string.replace(" ", "T") + timezone;
}
```

Then you can create the date as follows:

```
new Date(formatDateString("2013-01-01 00:00:00", "+00:00"));
```

Another way to convert local time to GMT is as follows:

```
var timezone = new Date("1970-01-01 00:00:00"); // this is the start of unix time
```

Now that you have your own local timezone as a date object you can do:

```
new Date(new Date("2013-01-01 00:00:00") - timezone);
```

All the above methods produce the same date at GMT.

Comment: All good ideas, except for the last one.  That won't hold up if the offset at `1/1/1970` is different than the offset at the input date.  Also, you could use a `Z` instead of `+00:00`, but both are valid.

Answer (score 0):

JS reads this with time zone that your computer uses.

You can try use `myDate.toUTCString()` for get date in UTC time.

If you want get timestamp use `myDate.getTime()`

Answer (score -1):

Mine works simply by doing this

```
var datetime= new Date()
```

However the month is 1 low so you have to add one