# Convert two different offsets to the same UTC date

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, momentjs

I have a Protractor test where I am making sure the date text in my element is equal to the current date. This doesn't always work because one value goes from UTC where the other grabs local timezone. How can I compare both these values to make sure they are the same date? Thanks.

```
var moment = require('moment');
var dateFormatted = moment().utcOffset(-420).format('MMM DD, YYYY');   // set to Arizona time
var dateInfo = element(by.css('.date'));
dateInfo.getText().then(function (dateText) {
  var textFormatted = moment(dateText).utcOffset(-420).format('MMM DD, YYYY');
  expect(textFormatted).toEqual(dateFormatted);
});
```

Comment: did you try to use [isSame](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/)?

Comment: You're confusing timezones with offsets, which are related but different.

Comment: @Artem I did not know about that before, but I've tried it and it is false

Comment: @torazaburo okay so how does the difference help me?

Comment: It doesn't help you. It's a matter of terminology. Just nit-picking.

Comment: @cocoa could you add the original date returned by `getText()`

Comment: @cocoa check [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/K1joUiXFwDqFb1HEKGwL?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. Using Aman's advice and doing `moment().utc()`, here's my solution:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var dateInfo = element(by.css('.date'));
var dateFormatted = moment().utc('MMM DD, YYYY').format('MMM DD, YYYY'); // set to UTC timezone
dateInfo.getText().then(function (dateText) {
  var textFormatted = moment().utc(dateText,'MMM DD, YYYY').format('MMM DD, YYYY');
  expect(textFormatted).toEqual(dateFormatted);
});
```

I used this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855842/moment-js-utc-gives-wrong-date) for a reference

Answer (score 1):

Convert both time to `utc` using `moment().utc()`

```
var moment = require('moment');
var dateFormatted = moment().utc().format('MMM DD, YYYY');   // set to UTC timezone
var dateInfo = element(by.css('.date'));
dateInfo.getText().then(function (dateText) {
  expect(moment(dateText).utc().format('MMM DD, YYYY')).toEqual(dateFormatted);
});
```

Comment: that doesn't work for me. i still get 'expected JAN 28, 2016 to equal JAN 27, 2016'.

Comment: These are the values I get unformatted: "2016-01-28T07:00:00+00:00, 016-01-27T19:04:26+00:00"

Comment: Dates are already UTC. To compare the UTC date, just use UTC methods. But two Dates on the same date in a particular time zone may not be on the same date UTC (or any other time zone).

Comment: "2016-01-28T07:00:00+00:00, 2016-01-27T19:04:26+00:00", clearly these time stamps cannot be same in 'MMM DD, YYYY' format if they have same timezone