# Format datetime to DD-MMM-YYY HH:mm:ss using moment.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have date in this format

```
2017-01-09T18:30:00.000Z
```

I am using moment.js and I am trying to convert it into `DD-MMM-YYY HH:mm:ss` --> `09-Jan-2017 18:30:00`

I have tried this method

```
dateTime = moment("2017-01-09T18:30:00.000Z").format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
```

But I got output like this `9/1/2017 0:00`
What I miss?

Comment: this `moment("2017-01-09T18:30:00.000Z").format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");` gives `09-Jan-2017 23:30:00` which looks correct

Comment: `YYY` is a bit odd (you get `172017`), other than that, [it looks fine](https://jsfiddle.net/b1z16gaf/).

Comment: @James But my problem is I didn't get time. It is showing 00:00:00. I can manipulate date format but how would i get time?

Comment: No idea - there must be something else going on that you're not showing us.  How are you inspecting/outputting `dateTime` for instance, because what you say you're getting doesn't match the format specifier at all, even the date part.

Comment: @James [it looks fine](https://jsfiddle.net/b1z16gaf/) this fiddle is also showing time like 00:00:00

Comment: @Pooja Uhh, the fiddle shows10-Jan-172017 05:30:00

Comment: It shows 20:30 for me, which is the GMT+2 time for the one you specified - 18:30. The reason (I think) it shows 00:00 for you is because (I assume) you live in India, and moment.js shows you the time with the timezone correction.

Comment: If that is all that's going on, and the rest of the output is in fact correct (I would have thought it would be `10-Jan-2017 00:00:00`), then your question is probably [a duplicate of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855842/moment-js-utc-gives-wrong-date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting 00:00 is because `moment` converts the date object to your timezone. In order to remove this and format the date without the timezone, use `moment.utc()`.

Update your fiddle to this:

`var dateTime = moment.utc("2017-01-09T18:30:00.000Z").format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
 document.getElementById('output').innerText = dateTime;`

and it will work, outputting: `09-Jan-2017 18:30:00`

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
dateTime = moment("2017-01-09T18:30:00.000Z").format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"); // note the extra Y in YYYY
console.log(dateTime);
// => 10-Jan-2017 05:30:00
```

For the most part it looks like what you are doing is right.