# momentJS: Getting wrong timestamp from date in a different timezone

Tags: node.js, momentjs, utc, moment-timezone

There is one time input i.e. start_time

I am trying to get timestamp in milliseconds for these inputs

```
let start_time = "17:05:00";
var start_date_moment = moment(start_time, "HH:mm:ss");
console.log(start_timestamp);
output is -> moment("2019-04-24T17:05:00.000")
```

This output remains same on server and local

But when I am trying to get unix timestamp in milliseconds in the same way

```
var start_timestamp = moment(start_time, "HH:mm:ss").valueOf();
```

On server at different timezone

```
console.log(start_timestamp);//1556125500000
console.log(moment(start_timestamp/1000).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'); //2019-04-24 17:05:00
```

On local

```
console.log(start_timestamp);//1556105700000
console.log(moment(start_timestamp/1000).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'); //2019-04-24 22:35:00
```

This start_timestamp value is different on local and server. But timestamp shouldn't change with timezone, it should remains same for all timezones. Please help me with this.

How to get the correct and same value at both places. I got this link some what related to this https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2035

There is no issue with dates any particular format, issue is only with timestamp.

Comment: I wrote an answer to explain the issue you are experiencing, if you need clarification or have additional question feel free to ask..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [moment.js - UTC gives wrong date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855842/moment-js-utc-gives-wrong-date)

Comment: @HereticMonkey no my case was bit different.  It was giving correct date in all formats, only issue was there in timestamp case.

Comment: [edit] your question to include why you think the answers on the other question to not solve your question.

Comment: Done @HereticMonkey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the offset into consideration when using moment (using [timezones moment.js](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/)). Since no offset was passed in the input, the moment will be based on the time zone of the computer the code is running on, hence the different values..

Example:

```
var a = moment.tz("2013-11-18 11:55", "Asia/Taipei");
var b = moment.tz("2013-11-18 11:55", "America/Toronto");

a.format(); // 2013-11-18T11:55:00+08:00
b.format(); // 2013-11-18T11:55:00-05:00

a.utc().format(); // 2013-11-18T03:55Z
b.utc().format(); // 2013-11-18T16:55Z
```

If you change the time zone of a `moment` object using moment-timezone only affects the value of the local time.  It does not change the moment in time being represented, and therefore does not change the underlying timestamp.

A [Unix Timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is **always** based on UTC - you can see it as the same timestamp at any given location in the world.

- [Official Moment Docs](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) on timezones

**Edit:**

If you use `utcOffset` you should pass an integer:

Example:

```
moment.utc("2015-10-01 01:24:21").utcOffset("-240").format('YYYYMMDD HHmmss ZZ')
// "20151001 012421 +0000"

moment.utc("2015-10-01 01:24:21").utcOffset(-240).format('YYYYMMDD HHmmss ZZ')
// "20150930 212421 -0400"
```

MomentJS allows offset-arguments to be passed as string, but it expects the string to be in one of the ISO8601 formats: `[+/-]HH:mm` or `[+/-]HHmm`.

To avoid this all together you could, if known, pass the location as an argument like

```
 moment.tz(start_time, "HH:mm:ss", "Asia/Kolkata").valueOf();
```

as mentioned in the first example above..

Comment: I tried using utcOffset also but then too it has given the result.  ```moment(start_time, "HH:mm:ss").utcOffset("+05:30").valueOf()```

Comment: string is also allowed. I just went through doc ```moment().utcOffset("+08:00");
moment().utcOffset(8);
moment().utcOffset(480);```   all three are same. Doc link https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/09-utc-offset/

Comment: Thats what I wrote in the last sentence, but it must be in the correct format..  let me edit my edit ;)

Comment: Thanks. My problem is solved with this -> ```moment.tz(start_time, "HH:mm:ss", "Asia/Kolkata").valueOf();```

Comment: Great,, I will add that to my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192322/discussion-between-tripathi29-and-iluvlogix).