# moment.js returning wrong day for a date

Tags: javascript, html, momentjs

I have a field with a value of `03-01-2020` as a date in DD-MM-YYYY date format. When I use

`moment.utc(document.getElementById('date').value, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss").toDate()`

and the value turns out to be a day behind as shown below:

`Thu Jan 02 2020 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)`

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [moment.js - UTC gives wrong date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855842/moment-js-utc-gives-wrong-date)

Comment: `a value of 03-01-2020 as a date in DD-MM-YYYY date format` - Could you show more of what this value is? This currently works okay for me

Comment: @Light it is an input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the line to the following:

`moment(document.getElementById('date').value + " 12:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss").utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")`

Based of this answer: [moment.js - UTC gives wrong date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855842/moment-js-utc-gives-wrong-date?answertab=active#tab-top)