# Unable to convert date to local from utc

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, momentjs

I have date from SQL database in the following format and its not being converted to local time properly even though moment object shows that its a proper UTC time.

```
var date = moment.utc('/Date(1622491200000)/').local().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')

console.log('date', date); // date 2021-06-01 01:00:00

Output should be **2021-06-01 06:00:00**
```

Comment: Hi @Waleed, what is your local time? Also what is your local time offset?

Comment: @Rena I am +5 into UTC

Comment: Hi @Waleed, I think you need check this answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/17856735/11398810.