# Moment displaying differently on devices

Tags: react-native, momentjs

I have the following code snippet here from one of my React Native project.

```
import moment from 'moment';

const format = 'mm:ss:SS';
const startPoint = moment(0).format(format);
```

Which it displays as

```
00:00:00
```

Which is correct. This displays correctly on Android and most IOS phones.

However on Iphone Mini 12, this displays as

```
30:00:00
```

I have no clue why this could happen. The timer works just fine in any other devices but on Iphone Mini 12, it behaves differently.

Is there any issue with Moment on Iphone 12 mini that i didn't know about?

Comment: Can you read this answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17856735/11135174. It may answer your question

Comment: do all the devices having same iOS version?