# JavaScript date object, does it use UTC by default?

Tags: javascript

When I do:

```
var myDate = new Date();
```

Does it use UTC timezone by default? Or could this vary based on client location?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6777470/2739235.

Comment: Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*<sup>From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)</sup>*

> If you supply no arguments, the constructor creates a JavaScript Date
>   object for today's date and time according to **local time**.

It only depends on your local time.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK It takes the date and time from the machine it's running on, and it will use whatever timezone it is given from the OS, so I believe it would change based on client location, providing they have their machine set up correctly.