# Parse date in GMT to date in UTC

Tags: javascript, parsing, date

Is there any way to parse date in GMT format into date in UTC format using JS? Or everything needs to be parsed manualy?

Basically, I search for a way to transform first string into the second:

```
Wed, 23 Apr 2014 09:15:42 GMT

2014-04-23T12:15:42.046 UTC
```

Does anyone know how this can be achieved? Every useful answer / JSFiddle is highly appreciated and evaluated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using a library, you can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for getting the exact format that you want:

```
moment.utc('Wed, 23 Apr 2014 09:15:42 GMT').format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS [UTC]');
```

This is the output:
`2014-04-23T09:15:42.000 UTC`

Please note that the `SSS` part of the date will be `000` since the original date doesn't have fractional seconds.

Now, if you use a new Date object, it will remove the deprecation warning and you can get this:

```
moment.utc(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS [UTC]');
```

Output:
`2014-04-24T14:10:38.395 UTC`

Comment: SSS can be ignored, right? Can I just write

 format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss [UTC]') ?

Comment: Yes, you can leave off the `SSS` part if you don't want the fractional seconds in the conversion.

Comment: Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.

Can I remove this message somehow or resolve this?

Comment: If you use a new `Date` object instead of a hard coded date string, it will remove the deprecation warning. I'm assuming you want the current time and not a hard coded date. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Please Check this out hope this answer helps u in some manner.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc)

Try this

```
    var now = new Date(); 
var now_utc = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(),  now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Answers with links are not good standard for SO.

Answer (score 1):

A very close to your output:

console.log(new Date("Wed, 23 Apr 2014 09:15:42 GMT").toISOString())

Prints: 2014-04-23T09:15:42.000Z (Z means UTC)

Comment: Yes, probably the best solution for now with pure JS with no additional libraries.