# Given a date/time and timezone, how do you convert that into a UTC timestamp?

Tags: javascript

I am calling an API that returns a date/time string such as `"2014-04-30 15:32:01"`.  On top of this, I have a known timezone that this date/time exists in.  I can see from the javascript `Date()` class has a `.UTC()` call for this, but that does not seem to accept a timezone as far as I can tell.

Given the date/time string + timezone, how can I convert those into a UTC timestamp?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do that in javascript. If you have a timezone, something like `Eastern Daylight Time`, there's no way to get the actual difference between that timezone and UTC in javascript, I'm guessing you would have to either find an API that can return the timezone offset based on strings passed to it, or use the serverside to do it.

Comment: take a look at http://momentjs.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you convert a JavaScript date to UTC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and [Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/).

Comment: Can you expand how you'd use Moment.js and Moment Timezone to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a timestamp using `Date.parse` from your local time (RFC2822 date format to include the timezone), create a date from that and use `Date.toUTCString` to get the UTC time. Not sure if it'll work with day light savings though.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3vXV6/ (will alert the date)

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString