# JavaScript - Parse UTC Date

Tags: javascript, date

How can I parse a simple date string and let JavaScript know that it's actually a UTC date? Currently, if I do `new Date('2015-08-27')` it converts it to my timezone.

Comment: I strongly recommend using [a library](http://www.momentjs.com) for that

Comment: Many different options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc

Comment: I want to stay away from libraries.

Comment: There is conversion, so your date might be the same .. You might not need to convert it to your timezone, what is the display of `new Date('2015-08-27').toISOString()`

Answer (score 47):

You can do append `'T00:00:00.000Z'` to make the time zone specific (`Z` indicates UTC)

```
new Date('2015-08-27' + 'T00:00:00.000Z')
```

Note that `new Date('2015-08-27')` is treated differently in ES5 (UTC) vs. ES6 (Local), so you can't expect it any correction to be work consistently if you were planning to to hard code it (i.e. don't do it)

---

Also, do note that your `console.log` might show you the local time corresponding to the UTC time the expression evaluates to (that tends to throw you off a bit if you are expecting UTC to be at the end for expression that evaluate to UTC times and your local time zone at the end for those that evaluate to your local time). For instance

```
new Date('2015-08-27T00:00:00.000Z')
```

could show

```
Thu Aug 27 2015 1:00:00 GMT+100
```

which is the **same** as

```
Thu Aug 27 2015 00:00:00 UTC
```

Comment: would be nice to have a fully fledged solution dealing with many strings and options on Date instantiation

Answer (score 4):

In some cases, when other solutions don't work, adding  `GMT` will help:

```
new Date('July 11, 2022, 16:22:14 PM' + ' GMT')
```

Comment: Thanks, this works more often. For me, using a date formatted like mm/dd/yyyyT00:00:00.000Z as the suggested option suggested does not work. Using mm/dd/yyyy GMT absolutely works though. Should be the accepted answer imo

Comment: @Themis that's because `mm/dd/yyyyT00:00:00.000Z` is not the correct format. It should be `yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00.000Z`, and this does work.

Answer (score 2):

This might be obvious to most, but I got stumped for a few seconds because my string already had `hh:mm:ss`, so it required a little bit of string manipulation.

```js
var d = '2022-09-14 13:20:31';
d = d.split(' ').join('T')+'Z';
var date = new Date(d);
console.log(date);
```

This version is more verbose, but feels sturdier to me.

```js
var d = '2022-09-14 13:20:31';
var [yyyy, mm, dd, hh, m, s] = d.split(/[^\d]+/);
var date = new Date();
date.setUTCFullYear(+yyyy);
date.setUTCMonth(mm-1);
date.setUTCDate(+dd);
date.setUTCHours(+hh);
date.setUTCMinutes(+m);
date.setUTCSeconds(+s);
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score -5):

Here is what I would do.

```
var current = new Date();
var utcDate = new Date(current.getTime() + current.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
```

Comment: time zone offsets are not always given in values divisible by one hour.  Iceland, for instance, has a half-hour time zone offset.

Comment: @JonTrauntvein Iceland uses GMT without any daylight savings. Delhi uses the UTC+5:30 however, if you're looking for a non-hourly timezone. There don't seem to be any countries observing UTC+0:30 although some have in the past.