# How to set same date for each user apart from their time zone?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am using Dynamics CRM 2011 and I've a Date of Contract field in Contacts with the format of Date Only. Now, I want each user to see same date apart from their time zone. So far, setting same time zone for each user and adding an offset of 12 hours to date are tried but they are not considered as the best solution.

Any suggestion will highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following js to calculate the utc time:

```
var crDate = new Date();
var offset = crDate.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
crDate.setHours(crDate.getHours() + offset);
alert(crDate);
```

The following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc) has a few more solutions