# how to make the timezone of date to UTC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timezone, date-format, utc

I have a filter that i use to convert date to UTC date.

```
.filter('utc', function(){
    return function(val){
        var date = new Date(val);
        return new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(),
                date.getUTCMonth(),
                date.getUTCDate(),
                date.getUTCHours(),
                date.getUTCMinutes(),
                date.getUTCSeconds(),date.getTimezoneOffset());
    };
})
```

So when i give the date  2016-06-18

It returns the date like this Sat Jun 18 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

The date is correct but its not reflecting the correct timezone.

I want it to return in UTC timezone, like Z at the end

Comment: Why not use something like MomentJS and MomentJS Timezone? Would make your life a lot easier.

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc)

Comment: no i just want t quick solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- The `Date` constructor does not have a parameter that accepts a time zone offset.  The parameter following `seconds` is `milliseconds`.  [Refer to the MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).
- You should not pass UTC-based values into the `Date` constructor where local-based values are expected.  Doing so will have the effect of tracking a completely different point in time.  You may think you're adjusting for time zone offset, but you are not.
- The `Date` object *always* has the following behaviors:

  - It tracks a single value, as returned by `.valueOf()` (inherited from `Object.valueOf`), or by `.getTime()`.  That value is the number of milliseconds elapsed since Midnight at the start of Jan 1, 1970, in UTC (ignoring leap seconds).
  - The vast majority of input and output functions work with the *local* time zone - that is, the time zone that is set by the computer where the code is running.  The functions that work with UTC typically have `"UTC`" in their name.
  - **It is not possible to get the `Date` object to use a different time zone**.  Any solution that claims otherwise is not considering edge cases.  In particular, "epoch-shifting" is a common approach that is fundamentally wrong, when used in isolation.  (Passing UTC values into local-time parameters is one implementation of epoch shifting.)
- If you're looking for a quick solution, consider `.toUTCString()` or `.toISOString()`.

  - Some browsers may also support the ECMAScript Internationalization API and let you do:  `.toLocaleString(undefined, { timeZone: 'UTC'})`
- [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) is a very common library for dealing with these sorts of issue, and fills in a lot of gaps that the `Date` object has.  Local-to-UTC is done like this:

  ```
  moment(input, inputFormat).utc().format(outputFormat)
  ```

  - Note that moment does a lot of its magic via epoch-shifting, but it hides this via a public API and new object type (a `moment` object), which provides a layer of safety that you just can't get with the `Date` object alone.
- Note that in your question you did not at all state what was in the `val` variable.  Depending on whether that is a number, or a string, and what format that string is in, the parsing behavior of the `Date` object may change considerably.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Date.prototype.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) for this.

You can modify your function to return

```
return new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(),
                date.getUTCMonth(),
                date.getUTCDate(),
                date.getUTCHours(),
                date.getUTCMinutes(),
                date.getUTCSeconds(),date.getTimezoneOffset()).toISOString();
```

Comment: but than it converts into string, i want a date object