# How to convert time with a timezone to UTC in javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to write a method in javascript that takes a date and time zone and then returns a new date thats in UTC.

For example if I give it

```
Date: 2016/06/21 16:00:00
Time zone: America/NewYork
```

I should get back

```
Date: 2016/06/21 20:00:00
```

I looked at moment js, but seems like they didn't have a utc timezone name.

Comment: Looks like the standard name for UTC in this format is `Etc/UTC`; have you tried that with moment timezone?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc

Comment: In Javascript, use Date.parse()

Comment: Jeremy, that answer just does a string formatting to make it look like a utc date. It does not convert time. For it to convert time to utc, it also has to know the time zone of the date that you are providing.

Answer (score 3):

Please try

moment.tz("2016-06-21 16:00:00", "America/New_York").utc().format();

It gives desired output

[refer this for details](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/)

Comment: This is correct, but note to the OP that if you have that date format you will need to specify a format parameter as well as it is not ISO8601