# Javascript: Convert date to UTC format

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following date in UTC format:
`2016-06-18T05:18:27.935Z`

I am using the code below to convert it to the following format `2016-06-18 05:18:27`
 so I can compared it in `MySQL` database against `updatedAt` column.

```
var date = new Date(lastRequest);
date = date.getUTCFullYear() + '-' +
    ('00' + (date.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
    ('00' + date.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) + ' ' +
    ('00' + date.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) + ':' +
    ('00' + date.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2) + ':' +
    ('00' + date.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2);
```

I need to get the date of the last record and convert its date back to UTC format.

Basically, how do I go from the following format: `2016-06-18 05:18:27` back to UTC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new Date('2016-06-18 05:18:27').toUTCString()
```

The toUTCString() method converts a date to a string, using the UTC time zone.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString

And in fact, your format maybe the result of this:

```
new Date('2016-06-18 05:18:27').toISOString()
```

And by the way, if you want to format the date, [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) or [fecha](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha) may be better.

You can also find similar answers in [How do you convert a JavaScript date to UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc)

Comment: I think the OP was trying to get **from** the UTC time string back **to** a javascript `Date`.

Comment: @2ps Well, by `new Date()`, everything will be ok. But I think store `string` (  maybe `varchar`? )for date is the mistake, in fact `timestamp` is a better type in MySQL.

Comment: Note that moment.js is not recommended anymore these days: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var date = new Date(Date.now());
date = date.getUTCFullYear() + '-' +
    ('00' + (date.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
    ('00' + date.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) + ' ' +
    ('00' + date.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) + ':' +
    ('00' + date.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2) + ':' +
    ('00' + date.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2);
print(date);
print(date.slice(0,10)+'T'+date.slice(11,19)+'.000Z');
```

2016-12-17 04:34:28
2016-12-17T04:34:28.000Z

http://rextester.com/SGDV59246

Comment: Thank you!  Is there a way to retain the same `.000Z` value?  i.e.  original was `2016-06-18T05:18:27.935Z` and after using your solution, it's `2016-06-18T05:18:27.000Z`