# Javascript Date UTC issue

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, utc

Here I am trying to convert a **date to UTC** and then converting same **UTC date** as new date. but the issue is that I am not getting same date which I passed. here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sorb999/5ortzfps/1/)

Here I am passing Date 11/2/2015 ie **2 November 2015**, then converting it to UTC format, then UTC to normal date using **new Date** but now it is returning me 11/1/2015 ie **1 November 2015**.

Thanks in advance.

```
var myDate = '11/2/2015';
var myDateObj = new Date(myDate);
console.log('my Date is \n' + myDateObj);

var tempDate = Date.UTC(myDateObj.getFullYear(),myDateObj.getMonth(),myDateObj.getDay());
var utcDate = new Date(tempDate);

console.log('my Date after utc \n' + utcDate);
```

Comment: Did you check the following post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc

Comment: are the dates too different?

Comment: Is `11/2/2015` November 2nd or February 11th? Use `2015-02-11` to eliminate confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getDay()` method does not return the day of the month see more at [js Date.getDay()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp)
so instead of that you need to pass the day of the month which you can get by `getDate()` see more at [getDate()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getdate.asp)

```js
var myDate = '11/2/2015';
var myDateObj = new Date(myDate);
console.log('my Date is \n' + myDateObj);

var tempDate = Date.UTC(myDateObj.getFullYear(),myDateObj.getMonth(),myDateObj.getDate());
var utcDate = new Date(tempDate);
console.log('my Date after utc \n' + utcDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here I am trying to convert a date to UTC and then converting same UTC date as new date. But the issue is that I am not getting same date which I passed.

All Date objects use a single UTC time value, so they are all inherently UTC and there is no need to "convert" them to UTC.

```
var myDate = '11/2/2015';
var myDateObj = new Date(myDate);
console.log('my Date is \n' + myDateObj);
```

You shouldn't use the Date constructor (or Date.parse) to parse strings, write a small function or use a library (e.g. [moment.js](http://momentjs.com), [fecha.js](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha)).

The following (replacing *getDay* with *getDate*):

```
var tempDate = Date.UTC(myDateObj.getFullYear(),
                        myDateObj.getMonth(),
                        myDateObj.getDate());
```

is just a lengthy way of copying a date. Far simpler to use:

```
var tempDate = new Date(myDateObj);
```

If you want to get UTC date values, use UTC methods such as *myDateObj.getUTCHours*, *myDateObj.getUTCMinutes*, etc.

If you want to get the UTC date and time, use [*toISOString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.toisostring) which returns values with offset 0000:

```js
// Create a Date for 2 November, 2016
var date = new Date(2016,10,2);

// Copy it
var dateCopy = new Date(date);

// Show local date and time
console.log('Local date and time:\n' + dateCopy.toString());

// Show UTC date and time
console.log('UTC date and time  :\n' + dateCopy.toISOString());

// Show UTC Date only
console.log('UTC date only      :\n' + dateCopy.toISOString().substr(0,10));
```

Answer (score 0):

I Used

> myDateObj.getDate()

and it is working fine and please check now.

```
var myDate = '11/02/2015';
var myDateObj = new Date(myDate);
console.log('my Date is \n' + myDateObj);
console.log('my Date is \n' + myDateObj.getDate());

var tempDate = Date.UTC(myDateObj.getFullYear(),myDateObj.getMonth(),myDateObj.getDate());
var utcDate = new Date(tempDate);

console.log('my Date after utc \n' + utcDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because it first converts the date to the long value as in milliseconds then to the date so 2nd november 00:00:00 it can take as 1st november 23:30:00 so you can give time also in the date as follow :

```
var myDate = '11/2/2015 23:00:00';
var myDateObj = new Date(myDate);
console.log('my Date is \n' + myDateObj);

var tempDate = Date.UTC(myDateObj.getFullYear(),myDateObj.getMonth(),myDateObj.getDay(),myDateObj.getHours(),myDateObj.getMinutes(),myDateObj.getSeconds());
var utcDate = new Date(tempDate);
console.log('my Date after utc \n' + utcDate);
```