# how to remove getTimezoneOffset

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I know that Date object is using machine timezone (where the code is running). I have a specific use case that I need to clear the offset.

```
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.getTimezoneOffset())
```

This print the offset from the UTC. 
I'd like to force the offset to be zero and I did this

```
var getTimezoneOffset = Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset;
Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset = function removeTimezoneOffset() {
    return 0;
  };
```

and I reset after I did something

```
Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset = getTimezoneOffset
```

This will fail in eslint complaining `Date prototype is read only, properties should not be added`. 
Is there any better way to remove the time offset?

Comment: Why do you need to clear the offset? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to print a date in UTC regardless of machine timezone.

Comment: Then use `Date.UTC` ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you convert a JavaScript date to UTC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the feeling that you're using some other code that uses *getTimezoneOffset* and rather that modify that code, you're changing the method.

Without knowing the specific issue, you could also just modify the date by the local time zone offset so that "local" methods return UTC values:

```js
function formatAsISO(d){
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'')+n}
  return d.getFullYear() + '-' + z(d.getMonth()+1) + '-' +
         z(d.getDate()) + ' ' + z(d.getHours()) + ':' +
         z(d.getMinutes()) + ':' + z(d.getSeconds());
}

var d = new Date();

// Local date
console.log('Local   : ' + formatAsISO(d));

// UTC equivalent
console.log('UTC     : ' + d.toISOString());

// Adjust so local looks like UTC
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + d.getTimezoneOffset());
console.log('Adjusted: ' + formatAsISO(d));
```

Which modifies the actual date, so you might need to pass a copy of it to the (unspecified) function.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `date.toISOString()`, or otherwise check this question; [How do you convert a JavaScript date to UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc)