# new Date() returns relative time and not UTC time

Tags: javascript, timezone, timezone-offset

When I go to my browser development tools and write new Date() in the console, it gives me the following

```
Mon Dec 18 2017 17:11:29 GMT+0200
```

I thought it suppose to return the UTC time.

The issue is that I have a server on AWS which writes UTC time to a DB. it writes it as a string and on the client side I do the following

```
const updatedMilliAgo = new Date() - new Date(timeStrFromDb);
```

For some reason the diff is two hours even due I check it right after the write in the server.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for Date and see that the UTC methods are?

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find the answer there...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you convert a JavaScript date to UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc)

Answer (score 7):

When you use `new Date()`, you are constructing a `Date` object using the current value of the system clock where the code is executing.  The `Date` object internally stores *only* a number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z (without consideration of leap seconds).  In other words, `Date` objects are always representing the UTC time.

However - there are many functions and parameters on the `Date` object that work in *local time*.  For example, when you call `.toString()` on a `Date` object, the computer's local time zone is applied to the internal UTC-based value, in order to generate a string that reflects local time.

In the case of `console.log` - a standard object like `Date` cannot be directly logged.  Instead, most implementations will log a string value.  How that value is created is entirely implementation specific, and *not* defined by the ECMAScript specification.  Many implementations will return the same local-time based value that `.toString()` returns.  Some (FireFox, for example) will return the same UTC based value that `.toISOString()` returns.  It would be reasonable for an implementation to return the actual number of milliseconds stored (`.valueOf()`), or some other representation.  If you need consistency, don't just log the `Date` object.  Instead, log the output of one of its functions that returns a string or a number.

You also asked about subtracting two date objects.  That will implicitly call `.valueOf()` on each object, subtracting their UTC-based internal values and giving you the number of milliseconds between them.  The most likely problem you are encountering is with how you construct the second `Date` object.  You didn't give an example of what `timeStrFromDb` consists of, but understand that how that string is formatted directly relates to how the `Date` object is constructed.  If you aren't using a standardized format, or you aren't clear on whether the value is based on UTC or a specific offset from UTC, your string may be parsed differently than you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```js
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toUTCString();
console.log(n)
```

Comment: What is Date? how do I define it? Date.UTC() in the console gives me NaN

Comment: I tried this but I can't do const updatedMilliAgo = new Date().toUTCString() - new Date(timeStrFromDb) because one a string and the other a date object

Answer (score -1):

I am late, but I didn't find the answer and I had to fight for hours vs the code... finally my solution was as simple as that:

```
        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        timeZone.setDefault(timeZone);
```

When you set the default timezone, all dates you create will be in that ZoneId that you specify.

I hope to help to someone.

Comment: The question relates to Javascript. I believe this answer relates to Java.