# How to convert Time to UTC given its timezone?

Tags: javascript

You have a date/time. You know it's from timezone xyz. How do you convert it to UTC?

JS doesn't have option to set timezone. Except `toLocaleString` which takes local timezone on system and converts it to provided one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript check it out

Comment: Do you know the timezone offset for _xyz_? What format is this _"date/time"_?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc

Comment: top answer there is to use the library... is that even an answer?

Comment: and I dont know the offset

Comment: @AmardeepBhowmick not it's not. That's convert local time to UTC. Mine is for time in xyz timezone convert it to UTC.