# How to move the time using UTC in sequelize

Tags: node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize and want to get depends on the date.
So when I write the code below, It works well.
But the problem is that since this is the UTC, the local time is different.
 I need to move UTC time.
For example, "2019-08-21T00:00:00.000Z - 04:00:00".
How can I make this condition ?
Thank you so much for reading.

```
   const total = await models.parcel.findAll({
      where: {
        createdAt: {
          [Op.between]: ['2019-08-21T00:00:00.000Z', '2019-08-21T23:59:59.999Z'],
        },
      },
    });
```

Comment: You want to convert time from local timezone into UTC?

Comment: Yes! And I want to change a little bit that UTC time after converting.

Comment: Then check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc