# get UTC date (not UTC string) in javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs, utc

I want to get utc date using moment or any other possibilities. `utcString = moment.utc(someDate)).format()` is giving utc string not utc date. I am not able to perform operations like `utcString.getDate()` , etc using this. Please help me in providing with utc date object.

`moment.utc(new Date()).toDate()` is converting date again to my local time.

for example: I want the string of utc format like `"2019-10-31T00:00:00.000Z"` to get converted to utc date and perform operations(like `getDate(), getFullYear()`, etc) which could be performed using Date() object

Comment: No. I want utc time not local time. Please go through my question

Comment: then you could use `moment().utc().format('DD/MM/Y hh:mm:ss A')`. You can get value in any format `date`, `month`,`year` etc. Check the documents [utc()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/)

Comment: Format method return string. Not date object

Comment: but this `moment().utc()` is again date. you can check

Comment: moment().utc().getTime(). Will not work. Please check

Comment: @NarendraJadhav - this question appears to be related to react-date-picker, based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57810435/get-utc-date-not-utc-string-in-javascript/57810939#comment102053565_57810768

Comment: Given the number of answers, it is probably impossible to save, and should be closed.

Comment: @qaz2625qaz first think, if you are using `momentjs` then please read the documents . In moment don't have method `.getTime()`. If we want to get time using moment then we need to use `moment().valueOf()`.

Comment: please provide me solution (irrespective of momentjs) to get utc date object.            I mean strings like  ```"2019-10-31T00:00:00.000Z"``` to date object

Comment: moment().valueOf() returns number not date object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you convert a JavaScript date to UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc)

Answer (score 16):

From [the MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) on the `Date` object:

> Creates a JavaScript `Date` instance that represents a single moment in time in a platform-independent format. `Date` objects contain a `Number` that represents milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC.

In other words, the `Date` object is simply an abstraction that contains a single value, and that value *always* in terms of UTC.  If you want to see that value, call either `.valueOf()` or `.getTime()`, or coerce it to a Number (ex: `+d`).

There are many features of the `Date` object that can expose that value in different ways, such as in a standardized string format, a human readable string format, or various other numbers that represent partial component values (ie. year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond).  Some of these functions use UTC when determining their output (such as `.toISOString()`, `.getUTCFullYear()`, etc.), and others use the computer's local time zone when determining their output (such as `.toString()`, `.getFullYear()`, etc.).

It's easy to get confused by this, especially if calling `console.log` directly on a `Date` object.  The thing to remember there is that the console logging functionality is *implementation specific*.  You may see a human readable string that looks like local time as if you called `.toString()`, but some implementations give you a string that looks like UTC time in ISO format as if you called `.toISOString()`.  Really, the implementation can do whatever it wants when it comes to logging.  It could print out [a hissing cat](https://xkcd.com/1179/).

To add to the confusion, the `Date` constructor takes its numeric parameters in terms of local time, so one might think `new Date(2019,8,5,0,0,0)` was a `Date` object in local time, but actually it's converting to UTC during construction and recording the corresponding timestamp.  One can pass `new Date(Date.UTC(2019,8,5,0,0,0))` to have those values interpreted as UTC, but the `Date` object itself *is in UTC either way*.

The key point is, don't think that because you *see* local time that the `Date` object is *in* local time.  It isn't.  It never is. Thus, asking for it in a *different* time zone is also not possible.  Asking for it in UTC is what you already have.

> I want the string of utc format like `"2019-10-31T00:00:00.000Z"` to get converted to utc date and perform operations(like `getDate()`, `getFullYear()`, etc)

You wouldn't call `getDate` or `getFullYear`.  Those functions internally ask for the computers's local time zone and apply it to the timestamp before determining their result.  Instead you would call for `getUTCDate` or `getUTCFullYear`, which do not apply the local time zone.

> ... Actually I am using react-date-picker. ...
>   *(from your comments)*

There are lots of date pickers out there.  If you don't get the functionality out of the one you're using, try another.

The best ones will do one of two things when it comes to time zones:

- They might offer a setting for the "mode" of the picker, typically either local or UTC, or perhaps a specific UTC offset or time zone ID.  This would allow you to pre-determine how you want the picker to behave with regard to its inputs and outputs.
- They might simply provide the input and output as a `String`, rather than as a `Date` object.  This would allow the picker to behave in a neutral way, and you would then interpret the user's selection in whichever manner you pleased.  (BTW, HTML5's `<input type="date">` works this way.)

Unfortunately, there are lots of date pickers that *don't* work that way and assume you simply want a `Date` object that is created based on local time.  To contend with that, you will need to lie a little bit.

For example, say I pick `2019-09-05` from a date picker that assumes my local time zone.  It does internally `new Date(2019, 8, 5)`, or perhaps it does `new Date("2019-09-05T00:00:00.000")`.  Either form would be interpreted as local time before the the `Date` object records the corresponding timestamp value.  But I didn't *actually* want that - I wanted the user to pick a UTC date. So I add this bit of code to adjust the object (`d`) returned from the picker:

```
d.setTime(d.getTime() - (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000));
```

This technique is called *epoch shifting*, as it shifts the basis of the timestamp away from (or towards) the `1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z` Unix epoch. In this case, it's the original `Date` object (the one created by the picker) that was created incorrectly, and thus the above shifts it back to the standard Unix epoch.

Keep in mind that this technique is all about having your user pick a UTC-based value, and get it back to a regular `Date` object.  It is *not* to be used to have your user pick a local-value and *convert* it to UTC.  For that you *must* used the functions designed for that purpose (`getUTCFullYear`, `getISOString`, etc.).

Comment: Does you suggestion to use epoch shifting contradicts to your comment “ This answer demonstrates another common implementation of "epoch shifting" which is dangerous in isolation, as it can fail near edge cases like DST transitions. Not recommended. – 
Matt Johnson-Pint 
 [Jun 20 '16 at 23:58](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc#comment63317490_11964609) ?

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim - Epoch shifting is a technique.  It's usually abused, so often not recommended.  It is ok as long as the shifted `Date` object is not exposed or returned.  For example, Moment.js uses it - but only internally.  In the case of this question, epoch shifting is being used to counteract the effects of a `Date` object being created based on the local time zone when it actually was intended to be based on UTC. So, shift to reflect the intent. Think of it as a hack of a workaround. It would have been much better if the picker created the `Date` object in terms of UTC to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript date object has functions for getting the UTC date, year, string, etc. You can find all of the different functions [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp). Example:

```js
let date = new Date();
console.log("UTC Date: " + date.getUTCDate());
console.log("UTC Year: " + date.getUTCFullYear());
console.log("UTC Hour: " + date.getUTCHours());
console.log("Full String: " + date.toUTCString());
```

Comment: Actually Iam using react-date-picker.   In which disabled property is used to indicate all disabled dates. For example disabled=new Date().    In react-date-picker package it is performing getTime() operation. So I can't modify its functionality to use getUTCTime().  Instead of that I want to pass utc date itself to that property. For example disabled=utcdate

Comment: Well then I believe that would be a setting within the plugin, as the `getTime()` function returns the time in epoch format, meaning somewhere in the plugin it would have to convert epoch time to the local time zone.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let d = moment();
let d_utc = moment.utc();
let full_year = d_utc.format('YYYY');
let month = d_utc.format('MM')
console.log(d);
console.log(d_utc);
console.log(d.format());
console.log(d_utc.format());
console.log(full_year);
console.log(month);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

You can format the date as you wish (local time or UTC) and put the result into variables.

Comment: not just year. I have to perform many things using utc date. so I want UTC date object

Comment: answer edited @gaz2625-gaz. hope will help you. best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using extra libraries by doing this fun thing:

```
var fooDate = new Date();
var utcDay = fooDate.getUTCDate();
fooDate.setDate(utcDay);
```

This will let you get the UTC date and update your already existing Date object with it.

EDIT: I'd recommend you checking Jesse's answer too, in case you need the whole thing in UTC format.

Comment: This works with a Date which is a day in js, not helpful, not useful.

Answer (score 0):

To convert `"2019-10-31T00:00:00.000Z"` to a Date object, you can try using `new Date()`. From there, you will be able to call methods such as getFullYear or getUTCString:

```
new Date("2019-10-31T00:00:00.000Z").getFullYear()
```

If you would like to use moment.js, you can get a native date using moment.toDate(). You can then call getFullYear(), etc, on the native date.

```
let time = moment.utc(new Date("2019-10-31T00:00:00.000Z"))
let UTCDate = time.toDate().getFullYear()
```

If you want a `Date` representing the current time, just call `new Date()`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199040/discussion-on-answer-by-ecc521-get-utc-date-not-utc-string-in-javascript).

Answer (score -1):

You can use JS Date class.

Create a Date instance : `let date = new Date();`

Then you can perform a lot of functionality on that date object. For example,

```
let d= new Date();
d.getDate()
//5
```

Answer (score -1):

I did not used any external library, in my case I have a hardcode text "UTC":

(i.e `We will delete your account at ${tomorrowUtc} UTC`)

So this is what I did:

```
const now = new Date();
const year = now.getUTCFullYear();
const month = now.getUTCMonth();
const day = now.getUTCDate();
const hour = now.getUTCHours();

const tomorrowUTC= new Date();
tomorrowUTC.setDate(day + 1); // +1 because my logic is to get "tomorrow"
tomorrowUTC.setYear(year);
tomorrowUTC.setMonth(month);
tomorrowUTC.Hours(hour);

// then use the tomorrowUTC for to display/format it
// tomorrowUTC is a "Date" and not a string.
```

This is kinda "hacky" as this is still using your local timezone, but if your goal is same as mine (to just display it with a hard coded timezone) then this would work.