# Js new Date() creates different GMT

Tags: javascript

I'm reading data from a API server:

```
opTMP:
     { DATAI: "2019-10-27T00:00:00", …}
     { DATAI: "2019-10-31T00:00:00", …}
```

then I create a new date:

```
 const opTMP1 = this.opTMP.map(x => Object.assign({}, x));
  for (const op of opTMP1){ 
   let d = new Date(op.DATAI);
   console.log(d);
...
}
```

but in console I got different results,one is GMT+0300 and one GMT+0200 :

```
d: Sun Oct 27 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
d: Thu Oct 31 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
```

because of that I got problems when comparing it,I want to get only day month and year,no time info needed,how can I reset both to the same time or to 0:00:00?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50130338/378779) describes how to convert a JS date to YYYY-MM-DD format (i.e. without the time). You can then compare two such dates, e.g. ``if ( ymd1 < ymd2 ) ...``.

Comment: It's daylight savings between these two dates, so the two would be an hour apart. In your case, they are shown (*correctly*) as being in two different time zones - the Summer timezone and the standard one. 1 hour apart

Comment: Are you sure it don't change from Summer time to standard time between those days? Many places have the change the last Sunday in October

Comment: @rypskar One date is in "Eastern European **Summer** Time" the other in "Eastern European **Standard** Time", so - yes, it's daylight savings.

Comment: @kmoser the compraing is one problem,I need as date and to have the same GMT on both cases

Comment: @mrapi what timezone are those dates in? If it's local (presumably Eastern European), then there really is no issue. If it's not local, then write them with the timezone they are in or in UTC, so they always have the same base.

Comment: both are coming from a DATE field,there is no timezone info there

Comment: So, from which timezone are you *into* the date field? Is it supposed to be local or UTC?

Comment: Work with UTC, closing as dup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you convert a JavaScript date to UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc)

Comment: @mrapi Why do you want to convert it to a ``Date`` object to begin with? If you just want to compare which is earlier than the other, compare them as strings.

Comment: So what is the exact problem? 1. `I got problems when comparing it`, 2. `I want to get only day month and year` and 3. `how can I reset both to the same time or to 0:00:00`.

Comment: my mistake.I found the real problem:comparing the days between Thu Oct 31 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time) and  Sun Oct 27 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time) gives  wrong 5 not 4.solved using this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38356944/3492996.thanks to all of yous

Answer (score 1):

Converting date to epoch time is good way to comparing the dates.

```
let d = new Date(op.DATAI).getTime();
```

Comment: This does not really answers the author question, which was about extracting the date part from a datetime string in order not to deal with time and timezone

Comment: Hi.I'm not interested in getting the time,only date part

Comment: This is the best for `"because of that I got problems when comparing it"`.