# How do I convert the current time to UTC?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a countdown script. I want to convert the date I created here into UTC.

```
var deadline = new Date("dec 31, 2019 21:00:00").getTime(); 

var x = setInterval(function() { 

var now = new Date().getTime(); 
var t = deadline - now; 
var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
var hours = Math.floor((t%(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))/(1000 * 60 * 60)); 
var minutes = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)); 
var seconds = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60)) / 1000); 
document.getElementById("day").innerHTML =days ; 
document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML =hours; 
document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = minutes; 
document.getElementById("second").innerHTML =seconds; 
if (t < 0) { 
        clearInterval(x); 
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "TIME UP"; 
        document.getElementById("day").innerHTML ='0'; 
        document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML ='0'; 
        document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML ='0' ; 
        document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = '0'; } 
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you convert a JavaScript date to UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc)

Comment: Side note: The string you're passing `new Date` is not in [the only format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format) that `new Date` is specified to parse. That means you're falling back on "implementation-specific behavior or heuristics" which is unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

```
var isoDate = new Date('yourdatehere').toISOString();
```

I got this answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc)

Comment: *"I got this answer from here"* Then you vote to close as a duplicate and/or post a comment. Answers that just copy other answers aren't useful.

Comment: I did vote this as a duplicate.

Comment: Great! (Also: Great stuff citing the source.) Then don't post an answer as well.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
I will do that the next time I catch a duplicate.