# Problems with ZonedDateTime object receiving on back-end

Tags: javascript, java, spring, timezone-offset, zoneddatetime

I've faced the problem of receiving of date from front-end.
I send date from front-end in the format `"2020-01-03T00:00:00+02:00"` to `ZonedDateTime` object in back-end. But instead of `2020-01-03T00:00Z[UTC]`, I receive `2020-01-02T22:00Z[UTC]` (actualy minus 2 hours).

**Question:**

Is there any way to make ZonedDateTime lib not to convert to UTC, or not to minus timezone? 
Maybe any annotation?

**Controller and object simple code example**

Object that came from front-end:

```
@DIfferentsLombokAnnotations
public class Filters {
  private ZonedDateTime startDate;

  //Other fields
}
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/ggg")
public List<ResponceObject> method(@RequestBody Filters filters) {
  //any code
 }
```

Comment: You have to format the date in ISO. take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc

Comment: Thanks, but actually problem with back-end

Comment: You are getting the correct point in time (only expressed differently, converted to UTC). No two hours have been subtracted. Maybe you want to pass a `LocalDate` instead. It’s a date without time zone or offset and without time of day, for example `2020-01-03`, so there is no way that the time could be wrong.

Comment: Is there a way to pass LocalDate using Moment .js lib?

Comment: And how I can convert It to ZDT to this value: 2020-01-03T00:00Z[UTC]? The main problem that I need only ZDT objecct

Comment: Actually I can't deserialize from "2020-01-03T00:00:00+02:00" this format on the frontend to LDT.

Comment: If you get a `LocalDate` through, you may convert using `yourLocalDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZonedDateTime only support UTC or UTC+2 which would explain why you're getting the result you have. One option would be to instead of sending a ZonedDateTime send a LocalDate, and LocalTime, and a ZoneId, and a ZoneOffset, then parsing to a ZonedDateTime on the backend. At the end of the day, a ZonedDateTime is already composed of these components.

Comment: Understand, but, unfortunately I can't change a front-end request because of a specific architecture. But thanks for answer.

Comment: Darn, okay, well if you always determine the offset you can just offset the ZonedDateTime by some offset. That might be a valid solution (sort of).

Comment: Of course, I have already realized this in this way... I took the timezone, convert it to sec, and used plusSeconds method to compensate lost hours. I just thought that there are the better way to do this, using spring or other fitches