# convert string to UTC time using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am trying to convert string to time, the string i have are in this format, '8:3' and '16:45'.

I want to convert UTC time in jQuery.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you convert a JavaScript date to UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc)

Comment: i have string like " 8:3 ", i want convert this string to UTC time

Comment: what does 8:3 mean?

Comment: " 8:3 " is time i have this time in string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your function to create UTC date with the time string.

```js
function toUTC(str) {
  let [h, m] = str.split(':');
  let date = new Date();
  date.setHours(h, m, 0)
  return date.toUTCString();
}

console.log(toUTC('8:3'))
console.log(toUTC('16:45'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for such operations. Just the simple `Date` object will do the trick. Say you want to convert time from a specific date.

```
let date = new Date('2020-04-01'); // leave the Date parameter blank if today
date.setHours(16); // must be 24 hours format
date.setMinutes(45);
let theUTCFormat = date.getUTCDate();
```

Cheers,