# Declare Javascript Date with Timezone to 0

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do I create a Javascript date without variable Timezone? Doing this in Javascript, gives a GMT Pacific standard below.

```
let test = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0)  },

test: Sat Feb 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)}
```

Would like no timezone, or timezone set to 0.

Comment: What timezone do you want to create one with? A `Date` is basically a number that points to a moment in time, so something like a date without a timezone doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Jacob make timezone zero

Comment: You mean UTC, GMT? Define 0. For me my time zone is zero and yours is pluses minuses wherever you come from.

Comment: hi @emix yes, UTC GMT, for some reason Angular is presetting mine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you convert a JavaScript date to UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc)

Comment: @Artportraitdesign1 that's not angular, that's a "feature" of your browser's JavaScript engine. Angular/Typescript is ultimately javascript when built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "make timezone zero" you mean to express the date/time in UTC, you can use [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC):

```
const date = new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 1, 1)); // February 1, 2020, UTC midnight
```

You can use `date.toISOString()` if you also want the date presented in an ISO 8601 format, which will use the UTC 0 offset

Comment: That's just how the date is output as a string. The date is UTC midnight, but `.toString()` on the Date presents it in your current timezone.