# is there any way to convert Time zone to specific time zone in React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, date, timezone

I use `Date()` function in react native to gave us current time from mobile.  and that date I store in firebase (firestore database). Now I want if any one see that date according his location date. like whatsapp,messenger etc messaging date.

for example

`June 9, 2022 at 10:31:44 PM UTC+5` date store from pakistan. if any one see that date from turkey so the date show according to  `UTC+3`

Comment: if you're storing dates in UTC all you should need is `utcdate.toLocaleString()` check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-to-convert-a-date-to-utc  and  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: Search [*\[javascript\] how to format a date*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+how+to+format+a+date). Consider using [*Intl.DateTimeFormat#formatToParts*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts) to get the parts and format as required.