# How to handle BST and GMT timezones on client side? Storing them in a DB as UTC

Tags: javascript, go

I've got a Go app and I store all datetimes as UTC:

```golang
dateTime, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z", myDateTime)
```

This becomes something like: `2022-09-29T19:40:36.150Z`.

Now I want to show this datetime client side (on a website), but showing the user the time in their timezone.

Since it's all UTC I could have the user pick their timezone from a list, like this one https://gist.github.com/valo/c07f8db33d223f57a4cc9c670e1b6050.

Then it's just a matter of adding/subtracting some time from the UTC and showing it.

But the problem is with daylight savings time, the client side timezone would have to change when it's summer, and change again when it's winter.

How are people doing this?

Comment: What specific issue are you facing? If you pass the UTC time then it can be converted to the users timezone for display ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#formats_of_tostring_method_return_values)) - you don't necessarily need to know what that timezone is. Things become more awkward when the server needs to know the timezone (so reports can be scheduled or timezone specific output generated server side). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/948532/11810946) may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, this happens on the client side. Information about the client's timezone is stored on the browser and is available to you if you need it. However, there are functions that sort this out automatically like `toLocaleDateString`.

**Step 1.**
Parse the time string `2022-09-29T19:40:36.150Z` to a Date object in javascript

**Step 2.**
Use `toLocaleDateString` on the date. This will display the Date in the client's timezone setting stored in the browser

[MDN docs for toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)