# Ignore/don't convert timezone?

Tags: javascript, datetime

My page was working fine and displaying dates and times as expected until I had to add `new Date()` to avoid the [momentjs](/questions/tagged/momentjs) [deprecation warning](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407).  Now my date is 5 hours off what it should be.

[image]

How can I fix this?  `vd` and `v` should both be 12:14:26 and, in this instance, fn should be "Seconds ago".

Here is the full code:

```
var k = key;
var v = obj[key];
var vd = Date.parse(obj[key]));
if (moment(vd).isValid()) {
    var fn = moment(vd).fromNow();
    v = fn;
}
return {
    name: k,
    value: v
};
```

I tried the following based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545708/parse-date-without-timezone-javascript), but it brought back the momentjs deprecation warning:

```
var vd = new Date(Date.parse(obj[key])).toUTCString();
```

(and still didn't work)

**__________________________________________________________________________________**

*Threaded comments would be cool*

> What happens if you just run `moment(v)`? Should work. – **Maggie Pint**

It does work, but I get the deprecation warning.

> I just looked closer. The format of V is ISO8601 with offset, so you shouldn't be getting a deprecation if you just call `moment(v)`. If you are, try `moment(v, moment.ISO_8601)` – **Maggie Pint**

Again, works, but I still get the deprecation warning.

> instead of `var vd = new Date(Date.parse(obj[key])).toUTCString();` did you try `var vd = new Date(Date.parse(obj[key])).toISOString();` ? or even simplier `var vd = Date.parse(obj[key])` – **user3**

With `.toISOString()` it outputs "Invalid Date".  `var vd = Date.parse(obj[key])` Is what I had originally, it works as expected but I get the warning.

> Your v string appears to use ISO8601 format already? Maybe append the Z, or ask moment to recognise it automatically as UTC when timezone info is missing – **Bergi**

I just tried `var vd = new Date(Date.parse(obj[key] + "Z"));` and it works!

Comment: Like it is explained is the link you provided the problem is that `v` is missing the timezone part, it should be something like "2016-09-14T17:31:40.403Z", you should modify the way you generate `v` to have something more standard

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over that. It's how it's stored in the [tag:intersystems-cache] database, as far as I can tell...

Comment: The moment deprecation warning means that you are using the parser incorrectly. The right work around is to specify the correct date format. If you show me your code, I can help you get around that format, and get your code not throwing the warning.

Comment: instead of `var vd = new Date(Date.parse(obj[key])).toUTCString();` did you try `var vd = new Date(Date.parse(obj[key])).toISOString();` ? or even simplier `var vd = Date.parse(obj[key])`

Comment: I just looked closer. The format of V is ISO8601 with offset, so you shouldn't be getting a deprecation if you just call ``moment(v)``. If you are, try ``moment(v, moment.ISO_8601)``

Comment: Also, why are you re-assigning v to the output of fromNow? Maybe you're then re-using v and that's how you get the deprecation warning?

Comment: Your `v` string appears to use ISO8601 format already? Maybe append the `Z`, or ask moment to recognise it automatically as UTC when timezone info is missing

Comment: Reusing `v` may be the issue.  I have added the full code.

Comment: What happens if you just run ``moment(v)``? Should work.

Comment: see edits......

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the deprecation warning on the usage of `moment(v, moment.ISO_8601)`? Because that should not throw. You might try adding the "strict" parameter like `moment(v, moment.ISO_8601, true)` or `moment(v, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS', true)`. Otherwise, you'll need to check if you're using `moment(something)` somewhere else.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan At some point I had changed the `if` condition to compare `v` instead of `vd`.  My later attempts were in fact throwing the deprecation warning on the condition.  Thanks!

Comment: So appending `Z` was the solution.  `var vd = new Date(Date.parse(obj[key] + "Z"));`

Comment: No need to do that.  If the input is UTC, then use `moment.utc` to construct the moment.  Don't use the `Date` object if you don't need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you're passing a value for `v` as an ISO8601 string without any offset specified.  It is ambiguous as to what point in time you are actually talking about.

Because of [changes in the ECMAScript specification](http://codeofmatt.com/2015/06/17/javascript-date-parsing-changes-in-es6/), the value will be interpreted as UTC by some browsers, and as local time by others.

The way to avoid this ambiguity is to *not* use the date constructor.  Anywhere you have `new Date` or `Date.parse`, you're introducing potential differences in behavior.  Just use moment's own parser, and be specific as to your intent.

```
// your input
var v = "2016-09-14T12:14:26.149";

// pick only one of these:
var m = moment(v);    // input is local time
var m = moment.utc(v) // input is UTC

// then proceed as normal
if (m.isValid()) {
  var fn = m.fromNow();
  // etc.
}
```

If the input is in some other time zone, or has some other specific fixed offset from UTC, then you have various other options for constructing the `moment` object.  But really, don't rely on the `Date` object to do the parsing. That's the whole point of the deprecation message.

If the input is *not* always in the expected format (you're looking for invalid inputs, etc.), then you should specify the *expected* format such that you don't get the deprecation warning. For example:

```
var m = moment.utc(v, "YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

This particular format is also available as a constant:

```
var m = moment.utc(v, moment.ISO_8601);
```

This, and much more are spelled out [in the Moment documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/).

Comment: It will only do that if your input is not in the format you showed.  In that case, you'd pass a second parameter containing the tokens describing the format being used.  But it's not required for the ISO8601 string that you showed.  Verify your input please.  Also, make sure you're not on an older version of Moment, in case you're hitting a bug that has since been fixed.

Comment: The [source code for the regex used by Moment](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/src/lib/create/from-string.js#L9) is illustrative. You could just copy-paste that line, then do `basicIsoRegex.test(obj[key])` and ensure it returns true.

Comment: Soooooo, if you noticed the whole "checking if it's a date" thing, that's because these are dynamic columns and they aren't always a date.  I have replaced Moment's `isValid()` with a custom `isDate()` function and it all works now.

Comment: Accepting as the answer since yours fixed the problem *when the input was as expected*.

Comment: You don't need to do that either.  Check out my update.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is when you create the date that recovered from the database... because it does not have the timezone... but you know it is "-0500", might be you can add that part hard coded... not ideal but it works

[Look at this example](https://jsfiddle.net/MarvinDeLaCruz/esnhs5b0/3/):

```
function getMoment(v){
    var vd = moment(v+"-0500");
  var result = "?";
  if (vd.isValid()){
    result = vd.fromNow();
  }
  return result;
}
```

Check the `getMoment()` function, you can just copy and paste and use it in your code.

Comment: Please include all code in the answer itself, rather than a link to somewhere else. Also, the way you've constructed your URL is incorrect.