# Creating and comparing dates inside CosmosDB stored procedures

Tags: javascript, datetime, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

There is limited guidance for CosmosDB stored procedures and their handling of  `new Date()` and the comparison of dates.

The following code is a CosmosDB stored procedure to 'freeze' the writing of documents after a given time. The property `currentDoc.FreezeDate` is in ISO-8601 format, e.g. '2017-11-15T13:34:04Z'.

*Note: this is an example of the situation I'm trying to understand. It is not production code.*

```
function tryUpdate(newDoc) {
  __.queryDocuments(
    __.getSelfLink(),
    { /* query to fetch the document */ },
    (error, results) => {
      var currentDoc = results[0]; // doc from the database
      // fail if the document is still locked
      if (new Date(currentDoc.FreezeDate) < new Date()) {
        getContext().getResponse().setBody({ success: false });
        return;
      }
      // else update the document
      /* snip */
    }
  );
}
```

My question is: within CosmosDB stored procedures, is `new Date()` affected by timezones, especially given that the database may be in a different region than the invoking code? Is the date comparison code here valid in all situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, CosmosDB is storing DateTime values without the corresponding Timezone, aka. not as DateTimeOffset. This means it should not matter where the code is executed, since it is always normalized to something like this:

```
  "2014-09-15T23:14:25.7251173Z"
```

> Javascript Date object are timestamps - they merely contain a number of milliseconds since the epoch. There is no timezone info in a Date object. Which calendar date (day, minutes, seconds) this timestamp represents is a matter of the interpretation (one of to...String methods).

(taken from [Parse date without timezone javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545708/parse-date-without-timezone-javascript))

In other words, no matter where you are in the world, `new Date()` will always have the same value internally.

If you want to remove uncertainty in exchange for readability, I would recommend only storing the seconds or milliseconds since the epoch (Unix Time). This is also what is used internally by date (`new Date().value` - milliseconds). Incidentally, the internal cosmos document field `_ts` is also a timestamp in epoch format.

Be aware that the value of `new Date()` might by off the 'correct global time` by a couple of minutes - I don't know if Azure/Cosmos guarantees a certain deviation window.

Comment: Great answer! This has put my mind to rest. Interesting caveat about the 'correct global time', too.