# Remove timezone information when creating a new Date in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, date

Following issue, when trying this line of code

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(new Date('2016-06-15 10:59:53.5055')));
```

I get `"2016-06-15T08:59:53.505Z"`, I would however expect `"2016-06-15T10:59:53.505Z"`

How can I remove the timezone from the `new Date`?

the issue is, I'm sending this Date via a http-post to an API. In the http.post command, the Date is stringified (right now incorrectly)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse date without timezone javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545708/parse-date-without-timezone-javascript)

Comment: @RonaldHaan I think not, the problem is, that I don't need a string but really be able to pass it to a http.post which then stringifies it

Comment: A timezone package like https://momentjs.com/timezone/ might help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not remove timezone information when creating `Date` object -- this is a deficiency of the API.

The dates created via various `Date` APIs are parsed according to provided timezone (if the given method supports it), or if missing, they assume your local machine's timezone; then internally they're represented as dates relative to the UTC timezone.

Whenever you stringify a date, you implicitly invoke `date.toJSON()` which in turn invokes `date.toISOString()`, which stringifies to UTC-relative time (hence `Z` as the end which stands for `Zulu` i.e. UTC).

As far as I can tell there's no method that serializes to ISO-like string but using local timezone. 
You could use [low-level Date properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype) to write your own method which serializes back to the local timezone if you really need to, or you could use a library like [`date-fns`](https://date-fns.org/v1.30.1/docs/format). You could use `moment` library, but while very powerful, it's *huge* so be careful with it.

Comment: Would you recommend to simply offset the time with the timezone just before posting it? Seems like to simplest way to go

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's possible you need to calculate time zone offset and add then add to your date object time sample code is given below.

```
var d = new Date('2016-06-15 10:59:53.5055');
    var timeZoneDifference = (d.getTimezoneOffset() / 60) * -1; //convert to positive value.
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (timeZoneDifference * 60) * 60 * 1000);
    d.toISOString()
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you