# Why new Date(yyyy-mm-dd) shows past date?

Tags: javascript

why its showing past day date

var date = new Date('2020-01-01');

console.log(date)

Tue Dec 31 2019 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

Answer (score 1):

Because of your timezone settings (Easter Standard time is GMT -0500 therefore 5 hours before 2020-01-01).

> Javascript Date object are timestamps - they merely contain a number
>   of milliseconds since the epoch. There is no timezone info in a Date
>   object. Which calendar date (day, minutes, seconds) this timestamp
>   represents is a matter of the interpretation (one of to...String
>   methods).

Basically it is the toString method that converts the date to your local timezone.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17545854/509977)

Comment: How should I fix it? how can I make it standard?

Comment: @developer Don't use `new Date(string)` or `Date.parse`. Instead use `Moment.js`.

Comment: @Dai Moment.Js also returning same result

Comment: @developer Please post a new question with your Moment.js code. I suspect you're missing some required parser options.

Comment: @pitto  so its an issue in the JS.  the date is exactly a date, without time or timezone