# Create a link to add event to yahoo calandar

Tags: javascript, yahoo

I am tying to generate a link to add an event to yahoo calendar. I am following this [documentation](https://github.com/carlsednaoui/add-to-calendar-buttons). 
My script look like this.

```
  var MS_IN_MINUTES = 60 * 1000;

  var formatTime = function (date) {
     return date.toISOString().replace(/-|:|\.\d+/g, '');
  };

  var calculateEndTime = function (event) {
      return event.end ?
             formatTime(event.end) :
             formatTime(new Date(event.start.getTime() + (event.duration * MS_IN_MINUTES)));
        };

  var yHDuration = (Number(Duration.split(':')[0]) * 60 + Number(Duration.split(':')[1]));

  var event = {
      title: 'Get on the front page of HN',     // Event title
      start: new Date(MeetingTime),   // Event start date
      duration: yHDuration,                            // Event duration (IN MINUTES)
      // If an end time is set, this will take precedence over duration
      address: 'The internet',
      description: 'Get on the front page of HN, then prepare for world domination.',
  }

  var eventDuration = event.end ?
      ((event.end.getTime() - event.start.getTime()) / MS_IN_MINUTES) :event.duration;

  // Yahoo dates are crazy, we need to convert the duration from minutes to hh:mm
  var yahooHourDuration = eventDuration < 600 ?
      '0' + Math.floor((eventDuration / 60)) :
      Math.floor((eventDuration / 60)) + '';

  var yahooMinuteDuration = eventDuration % 60 < 10 ?
      '0' + eventDuration % 60 :
      eventDuration % 60 + '';

   var yahooEventDuration = yahooHourDuration + yahooMinuteDuration;

      // Remove timezone from event time
      var st = formatTime(new Date(event.start - (event.start.getTimezoneOffset() *
      MS_IN_MINUTES))) || '';

   var href = encodeURI([
       'http://calendar.yahoo.com/?v=60&view=d&type=20',
       '&title=' + (event.title || ''),
       '&st=' + '20200611225200',
       '&dur=' + (yahooEventDuration || ''),
       '&desc=' + (event.description || ''),
       '&in_loc=' + (event.address || ''),
        '&invitees=' + (InviteesArr || ''),
    ].join(''));

   var link = '<a class="icon-yahoo" target="_blank" href="' +
       href + '">Yahoo! Calendar</a>';

   console.log(link);
```

My Start time looks like this, `6/12/2020 11:06:00 AM`. the generate [link is like this](https://calendar.yahoo.com/?v=60&view=d&type=20&title=Get%20on%20the%20front%20page%20of%20HN&st=20200611225200&dur=0300&desc=Get%20on%20the%20front%20page%20of%20HN,%20then%20prepare%20for%20world%20domination.&in_loc=The%20internet&invitees=). Duration is correct. But start time is incorrect. I am confused with the

```
st
```

parameter and using the timezone.

Comment: Try `20200612110600`

Comment: @Viney where should I use it?

Comment: I meant here like `'&st=' + '20200612110600',`

Comment: @Viney it's still the same

Answer (score 1):

What I think you need is this, because your are passing the string to the `&st=` query parameter when you already have correct start date stored in variable `st`:

```
var href = encodeURI([
       'http://calendar.yahoo.com/?v=60&view=d&type=20',
       '&title=' + (event.title || ''),
       '&st=' + (st || ''),
       '&dur=' + (yahooEventDuration || ''),
       '&desc=' + (event.description || ''),
       '&in_loc=' + (event.address || ''),
        '&invitees=' + (InviteesArr || ''),
    ].join(''));
```

And to answer your question about `st`. If you check this article - [Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) there it says that method returns the time zone difference, in minutes, from current locale (host system settings) to UTC.

And if you check the second answer from this post [Parse date without timezone javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545708/parse-date-without-timezone-javascript)
 subtraction after multiplying minutes returned with `getTimeOffset()` with milliseconds stored in `MS_IN_MINUTES` is necessary for your date to work correctly around the globe for all users.