# Date/time difference issue on Save - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

In my angular application, I have separate date and time controls. I am concatenating them using

```
new Date(datePipe.transform(dt, 'yyyy/MM/dd').concat(' ' + tm));
```

The problem is when I save the data to database, it is saving 4 hours ahead of the time that I am selecting.

Can someone please help? What do i need to do so that the time that i select gets saved exactly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse date without timezone javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545708/parse-date-without-timezone-javascript)

Comment: Whats dt and tm?

Comment: thanks heretic monkey, i can use that!