# How to remove GMT from time in JS/HTML while using library

Tags: javascript, html

I've been searching for hours to how remove GMT from time on my website. I saw a lot of topics but couldn't apply them in my code; I'm newbie in JS.
I have the following code:

```js
var timestamp = '<?=time();?>';

function updateTime() {
  $('#time').html(Date(timestamp));
  timestamp++;
}
$(function() {
  setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
TIME: <span id="time"></span>
```

Which give me the following output:

*TIME: Wed Oct 27 2021 00:26:01 GMT+0530 (US Standard Time)*

But i Want only:

*TIME: Wed Oct 27 2021 00:26:01*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse date without timezone javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545708/parse-date-without-timezone-javascript)

Comment: use `let a= "TIME: Wed Oct 27 2021 00:26:01 GMT+0530 (US Standard Time)" ; a.substr(0,30)`

Comment: BOO1 where exactly should i insert them in my code? and increment is for making it real-time and showing the seconds changing every 1 second

Comment: @AlokPrakash can you please show me where to add them and remove which part of my code?

Comment: You can use [moment js](https://momentjs.com/) to get what you want pls do check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(()=> {
        let d = new Date;
        $('#time').html(`${d.toDateString()} ${d.toLocaleTimeString()}`);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, brother. It did work. very nice

Answer (score -1):

Use `String.prototype.substr()`. See docs - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

```
function updateTime() {
  $('#time').html(Date().substr(0,25));
}
$(function() {
  setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
});
```

Comment: thank you, I think the @tdjprog method looks more standard, as the total number of characters that should be removed, might need to be changed in different time zones.