# How to convert "YYYY-MM-DD" format to Date object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have date in the format of **"YYYY-MM-DD"** i need to convert it into **Mon Feb 21 2022 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)** format

Comment: `new Date(string)`?

Comment: new Date("2022-02-17").toString()??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you convert a JavaScript date to UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc)

Comment: More answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/parsing-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545708/parse-date-without-timezone-javascript

Comment: How is 2022-02-17 equal to 2022-02-21 [05:30:00]?

Comment: @cmgchess  thanks dude working fine

Comment: @cmgchess How does `.toString()` help in converting to date object?

Comment: What did you try? What didn't work?

Comment: @cmgchess  I just wanted to convert "YYYY-MM-DD" date to above asked format.

Comment: @phuzi i guess i didnt read the question properly.  thought he needed to format that way

Comment: @BahubaliAk Not sure how 17th Feb becomes 22nd Feb! Guessing that's a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `new Date('2022-02-17')`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use new Date()

```js
new Date('2022-02-17')
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the title, you can simply just initialize a Date object by using the string you have

```js
const date = new Date("2022-02-17");
```

Now formatting it into something else can be a tedious to do. Using library such as [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) would be easier.

Javascript has a native method closer to what you want:

```js
new Date("2022-02-17").toLocaleString('hi-IN', { timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata" })
```

will return: `'17/2/2022, 5:30:00 am'`.

Now formatting it to something else IMO should be in a different question since the title of this question is already answered.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Luxon for date manipulation in Javascript.

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';
const dt = new DateTime.fromISO("2022-02-17");
const formatted = dt.toLocaleString(DATETIME_FULL);
```

In your question the date you want to convert it to is 4 days ahead. If this isn't a typo, you can also add days to the date object like this:

```
const addDays = dt.plus({ days: 4 });
```

[Docs](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/)