# Change Timezone for Date variable

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I have a string, and I have converted it into a Date variable. But the timezone is turning out to be wrong.

The string I'm trying to use is :

```
var v = "2013/09/05 17:53 -05:00";
var parsedvalueInField = new Date( v );
```

If I do an alert of parsedvalueInField,the output I get is:

```
 Thu Sep 05 2013 18:53:00 GMT-0400 ( Eastern Daylight Time);
```

How do I go about rectifying this difference in Timezone?

Please Help!

Answer (score 2):

`2013/09/05 17:53 -05:00` is the same time as `Thu Sep 05 2013 18:53:00 GMT-0400`; both are `Thu, 05 Sep 2013 22:53:00 GMT`

In *JavaScript*, you have two choices (natively) about how to display a time; in the local machine's timezone (`Date.prototype.toString`) or in *UTC* (`Date.prototype.toUTCString`). If you want to display a time as a string with a different time zone, you will have to write a function to do it manually, calculating it from *UTC*.

The two main articles on MDN which will help you with how to use a *Date* are [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and [`Date.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype).

Comment: For more info on UTC: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp, also check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439630/how-do-you-create-a-javascript-date-object-with-a-set-timezone-without-using-a-s

Comment: @Barrett please don't use w3schools as a primary reference; it is entirely seperate to the w3c and is not a wiki. http://www.w3fools.com/ . Use places like MDN or official w3 documents.

Comment: sorry i didn't know, MDN UTC https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC