# JavaScripts treats dates received from service as UTC Format

Tags: javascript, date

I have to display dates received from the service in UI using javascript.

```
 var now = new Date ('2015-09-26T09:52:19');
 alert(now) // it alerts Sat Sep 26 2015 02:52:19 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

I am in PST timeZone, I am wondering why Javascript treats date received as UTC.

One more observation is if i remove "T"  from date. Javascript doesn't treat it as UTC date.

Comment: Why do you have the T there at all?

Comment: Its coming from Service in that format.. All the dates has T

Comment: the client has no idea what timezone it is - you should treat  all date times as UTC to make things simpler.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643351/change-timezone-for-date-variable

Comment: My confusion is why it treats date as UTC is T is present in string.

Comment: @DanielA.White the client does in deed 'know' (although it may not be correct) `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` which for some weird reason returns it in *minutes*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Javascript does not have native support for timezones. When you create
>   a date in Javascript from an ISO string that is in the site's
>   timezone, the Date object will automatically be converted into the
>   browser's local timezone (which may be different than the site's
>   timezone). Strings with no timezone specified are also created in the
>   browser's local timezone."  - Jason Yuen, Aug 25 2013, Dealing with Timezones in Javascript [Nulogy.com](https://nulogy.com/articles/dealing-with-timezones-in-javascript#.VhZ1RhOqqko)

Have a look into momentjs (www.momentjs.com) if you wish to convert easily between timezones.

This is taken directly from their website.

```
var newYork    = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");  
var losAngeles = newYork.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles");  
var london     = newYork.clone().tz("Europe/London");  

newYork.format();    // 2014-06-01T12:00:00-04:00  
losAngeles.format(); // 2014-06-01T09:00:00-07:00  
london.format();     // 2014-06-01T17:00:00+01:00
```

Comment: One more observation - Only for chrome its getting converted to local time zone for other browsers date is treated as local time zone date..