# comparing javascript Date Objects

Tags: javascript, date

I have to do the logic for when to renew a refresh token and somehow I do not get the correct values.

```
 console.log(this._accessToken[".expires"]);
 console.log(Date.parse(this._accessToken[".expires"]) > new Date().getTime());
```

results in

```
Wed, 16 Oct 2013 15:42:53 GMT 
true
```

It should return false.

How to i make the new Date() be in the same timezone as the string. (I assume the string has all the information it need to tell if the current time is before or after it).

Comment: What does `this._accessToken[".expires"]` contain?

Comment: @ComFreek "Wed, 16 Oct 2013 15:42:53 GMT", as the first console.log() call says.

Comment: The better question would be "*When did you execute this?*" :-) Btw, the log looks like the token did contain a `Date` object, not a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be worrying about timezones if you're comparing Unix timestamps (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439630/how-do-you-create-a-javascript-date-object-with-a-set-timezone-without-using-a-s) as to why).

You're doing the comparison correctly -- you're getting `true` instead of `false` because that's correct:

```
> new Date()
Wed Oct 16 2013 11:51:29 GMT-0400 (EDT)
> Date.parse("Wed, 16 Oct 2013") > new Date().getTime()
false
> Date.parse("Wed, 16 Oct 2013 00:00:00 GMT") > new Date().getTime()
false
> Date.parse("Wed, 16 Oct 2013 23:00:00 GMT") > new Date().getTime()
true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a new date with the string your database returns and compare them using the usual operators:

```
var expirationDate = new Date("Wed, 16 Oct 2013 15:42:53 GMT");
var now = new Date();
alert(now > expirationDate);
```

<kbd>**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T2rHY/2/)**</kbd>