# Proper way to convert javascript Date timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, mongodb, date

I'm working with an API that returns time values in the following format:

```
2013:02:27T06:39:25
```

Note the lack of any identifier for timezone.

**From the API Docs:**

https://partner-api.groupon.com/ledger

```
"Transaction timestamp of the ledger entry in the affiliate's time-zone.. The format is YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.. Example 2013:02:27T06:39:25"
```

Apparently the API response time zone is EST (the affiliate's time-zone). What is the best way to derive a UTC timezone value from this for storage in a MongoDB database.

Comment: Check this answer [How do you create a JavaScript Date object with a set timezone without using a string representation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439630/how-do-you-create-a-javascript-date-object-with-a-set-timezone-without-using-a-s). There is example of `parseISO8601String()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The format is YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.. Example 2013:02:27T06:39:25"

It looks like there is a mistake in this [documentation example](https://partner-api.groupon.com/ledger) as it doesn't match the suggested format (`2013:02:27T06:39:25` should be `2013-02-27T06:39:25`).

The sample response later on that page *does* match the expected format:

```
"orderDate": "2012-11-21T04:57:03"
```

I would suggest using [`moment-timezone`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) -- it has a [`moment.tz()` constructor](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/how-to/constructor/) which will parse the date string and set the expected time zone:

```
> var moment = require('moment-timezone');
> var orderDate = moment.tz("2012-11-21T04:57:03", "America/New_York")

> orderDate.toString()
'Wed Nov 21 2012 04:57:03 GMT-0500'

> orderDate.toISOString()
'2012-11-20T17:57:03.000Z'
```