# MomentJS set timezone

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Because of how we store dates I need to set a moment object to timezone +0000.

I've tried using a variety of ways:

```
var d = moment().hour(0).minute(0).second(0).millisecond(0).zone('+0000');
var d = moment().hour(0).minute(0).second(0).millisecond(0).utc(0);
var d = moment().hour(0).minute(0).second(0).millisecond(0).utc();
```

When I console.log these dates they come out with the time `00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)`

Looking at the documentation it seems to say that `.utc()` and `.zone()` are for printing a format only, is this true? (This is the same I've seen with other questions on here, none address setting the actual object to a timezone it seems)

After I set and then manipulate the date I convert it to the JS Date object to use with angular-ui bootstrap datepicker (note: it was a moment object which I used console.log on).

Comment: Why not try "ISO 8601" format?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, where/how should I use the format?

Comment: Why do you need the timezone? To write to the server or the client?

Comment: To the server. Because it is storing the date as as 23:00:00 for the day before.  And since a lot relies on the saving method I would prefer not to make alterations there

Comment: To create a new object "moment" based on a timezone "+0000" you need to use this `moment ('2015-05-06T23:00:00.000Z')`.

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 6):

> Unless you specify a timezone offset, parsing a string will create a
>   date in the current timezone.
>   http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Example: You can tell in which timezone is your date using
`moment ('2015-05-06T23:00:00.000Z')`.

If you need to convert this to a specific timezone you can do so:
`moment().utc(0).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z')`.

About Timezone in Javascript: [How do I specify the time zone when creating a JavaScript Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834411/specify-timezone-in-javascript)