# current time plus one hour condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am stuck with one condition where I have to change the path based on time.

I will have two date variables, `CheckInStartDate` and `CheckInEndDate`, which will be coming from API.
Current time is system date time.

Path has to change in two conditions.

1. `CheckInStartDate` minus 1 hour of current time
2. `CheckInEndDate`   plus 1 hour of current time.

This is the code I currently have.

```javascript
$scope.checkIn = function() {
    var ONE_HOUR = 60 * 60 * 1000; /* ms */
    $scope.checkInStartDate=  01/16/2017 09:06:00 AM;
    $scope.checkInEndDate=  01/16/2017 11:06:00 AM;
    var checkInStartDate=$scope.checkInStartDate;
    var checkInEndDate=$scope.checkInEndDate;
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var checkinStartDate=new Date(checkInStartDate);
    var checkinEndDate = new Date(checkInEndDate);

    if ((checkinStartDate.getTime()) > (currentDate.getTime() - ONE_HOUR) ||
            (checkinEndDate.getTime()) < (currentDate.getTime() + ONE_HOUR)) {
        $location.path('/checkIn')
    }
    else{
        alert("cannot checkin");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? Your code looks mostly fine to me, except that initially setting `$scope.checkInStartDate` the way you do is a syntax error (and similarly for the end date).

Comment: You forgot quotes around the date-time in lines 3 and 4.

Comment: Can you not use https://momentjs.com/? it would make modifying the dates easier?

Comment: $scope.checkInStartDate and end date i will get from db just i am showing the axample

Comment: Are you sure the logical ´OR´ is correct and that it shouldn't be an ´AND´?

Comment: @Justastudent i have to change the path where if $scope.checkInStartDate is 9:06 am and current time is 8:06am  and similarly for $scope.checkInEndDate is 11:06 and current time is before 12:06 the path has to change

Comment: That is almost what your code is doing. If I understand you correctly, you may want an AND instead of an OR as @HubertGrzeskowiak suggested. If not: what do you want to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: Something I thought of just now: your code might not work correctly when the API is returning times in a different timezone than your system is in. If that is the case, you have to explicitly set the timezone when constructing `Date` objects.

Comment: @Justastudent i have changed OR to AND but also it is going to else condition. I have given checkInStartDate as 1pm and checkInEndDate as 5 pm it is not working

Comment: @Justastudent How to set timezone  objects

Comment: There are different ways, you may want to read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834411/how-do-i-specify-the-time-zone-when-creating-a-javascript-date) and the answers to it. You can check if this is the problem using `console.log` on all three dates.

Comment: @Justastudent iam getting dates like Mon Jan 16 2017 06:22:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) in pst times. I have changed my sytem ttime also to PST my current time is Mon Jan 16 2017 02:27:55 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak i have changed OR to AND but it is not working can u please check my code once

Comment: We cannot check anything unless you tell us what you are trying to achieve. Please define the expected behaviour.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak i have to change my path based on the below condition if any one condition is true path has to change.I will get two dates checkInStart and checkInEnd . If current time is 5Am and checkInStart time is 4 Am and checkInEnd time is 8Am then condition is true. this condition must be true till current time is from 3AM to 9AM.

Comment: @SudhirMN this means that not "any condition" must be true but both at the same time.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak must be true between  4am to 9am. if  Checkinstart is 3Am and CheckinEnd is 8 am

Comment: If @HubertGrzeskowiak's answer is not what you are looking for, please put some testcases in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kovxxp5n/) to show us what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly, you want to allow check-in in the time period between the following two times:

- CheckInStartDate minus 1 hour
- CheckInEndDate plus 1 hour

Let's call the first point `s` and the second point `e`. The current time is `c`. In this case your condition should be true when

```
s < c < e
```

In JavaScript this is equivalent:

```
var s = new Date($scope.checkInStartDate).getTime() - ONE_HOUR;
var e = new Date($scope.checkInEndDate).getTime() + ONE_HOUR;
var c = new Date().getTime();
if (s < c && c < e) {
    // check-in allowed
} else {
    // not allowed
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur solution