# Generating Timestamps according to user's timezone for `User-Friendly Personalization`

Tags: javascript, datetime

I need to get the end of the month in epoch time according to each user's timezone to provide user-friendly experience.

As an example for a user in Sri Lanka, it could be March while in the US it's still February. I need a reliable way to calculate the timestamp without interference from the server locale time. So I could host it anywhere in the world without running into a problem

It should be calculated as follows,

- get current year and month according to the `locale timezone`

> I tried to use `Intl API` but couldn't figure out

- then get the last day of this month or fisrt day of next month

```
new Date (locale_year,locale_month+1,0)
```

- convert to [epoch](/questions/tagged/epoch) timestamp

```
.valueOF()
```

tried to use the timezone option `TimeZone` in `JS Intl API`

Comment: You can use libraries like moment js for the same.

Comment: I need a light weight solution

Comment: So you want to run the code on your server, but using the user's timezone not the server system timezone? Then in what format do you get the user timezone?

Comment: Epoch timestamp. because I need to give access to resources for certain amount of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting with all the [`Date.prototypes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) & [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat)

> This function helps to make logic according to the each user's Timezone. Without the unforseen server localtime interference

> Visit the [`IANA time zone database`](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) for more timezone identifiers, such as `Asia/Shanghai`, `Asia/Kolkata`, `America/New_York`.

```
function dateWithTZone (timezone,date){

    const options = {
      year: "numeric",
      month: "numeric",
      day: "numeric",
      hour: "numeric",
      minute: "numeric",
      second: "numeric",
      hour12: false,
      timeZone: timezone,
      timeZoneName: "longOffset",
    };
    const dateArray = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", options).formatToParts(date);
    const dateObj = dateArray.reduce((acc, cur) => ({...acc,[cur.type]: cur.value}),{});
    const {hourOffset,minuteOffset} = getOffset(dateObj.timeZoneName)
    return {...dateObj,hourOffset,minuteOffset}
}
```

```
function getOffset (timeZoneName){
    return {
      hourOffset: parseInt(
        timeZoneName.slice(3, 4) + timeZoneName.slice(4, 6)
      ),
      minuteOffset: parseInt(
        timeZoneName.slice(3, 4) + timeZoneName.slice(7, 9)
      ),
    };
}
```

> `month` returned from `dateWithTZone()` has values `1-12`. Normally Javascript month values are from `0-11`.

```
// get the timezone from the user. here I use "Asia/Kolkata"
const {year,month,hourOffset,minuteOffset} = dateWithTZone("Asia/Kolkata",Date.now())
// I wanted to get user's current month end timestamp 
Date.UTC(year,month,1,-hourOffset,-minuteOffset)
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP wants. It will get the offset for now, not for the required date and time. Offsets change due to daylight saving and historic changes, you can't assume it was or will always be whatever it is now. See [*How to initialize a JavaScript Date to a particular time zone*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-a-particular-time-zone) and [*How do I specify the time zone when creating a JavaScript Date?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834411/how-do-i-specify-the-time-zone-when-creating-a-javascript-date)

Comment: If anyone needs the  daylight saving and historical changes ,consider using [`getTimezoneOffset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset#gettimezoneoffset_and_dst) .Thanks for the help [RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg)