# Javascript getDay() returns wrong result

Tags: javascript, date

My code

```
var d = new Date("2014-09-01"); 
var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
days[d.getDay()]
```

I expects 
`days[d.getDay()]` returns Monday but It got Sunday

I am located in Pacific Time California zone

Do I miss something?

Comment: It returns monday for me, as it should -> http://jsfiddle.net/s1bse8fm/

Comment: Your fiddle gave me Sunday in FF, IE and Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dan Tao is right, here's how you can fix the missing timezone.

```
var d = new Date("2014-09-01"); 
var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
d.setTime( d.getTime() + d.getTimezoneOffset()*60000 );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s1bse8fm/2/

Related: [How do you create a JavaScript Date object with a set timezone without using a string representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439630/how-do-you-create-a-javascript-date-object-with-a-set-timezone-without-using-a-s)

Answer (score 1):

The string you're passing to the constructor, `"2014-09-01"` does not indicate a time zone. On both Chrome and Firefox (based on my tests right now), this seems to be interpreted as a GMT date. When you call `getDay()`, the day is given in your local time zone.

So in my case, since I am in California, the date `2014-09-01`, which is midnight in GMT, is actually 5pm on August 31 in PDT.

Comment: How to I include timezone in the passing in string `2014-09-01`?

Comment: @icn - var d = new Date(aYear, aMonth, aDay);
d.setTime( d.getTime() + d.getTimezoneOffset()*60000 );