# Javascript returning incorrect date from an input type date

Tags: javascript, date

when i select a date say 12/03/2014 it retuns Tue Dec 02 2014 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) one day before what i entered?

```
 <script>

function getAge() {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(document.forms["name"]["birth"].value);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();

    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate()+1)) {
        age--;
    }
    document.getElementById('age').innerHTML = birthDate;
}
</script>

<form name='name' onsubmit='return false'>
  <input type="date" name="birth">
<p id='age'></p>
<button onclick='getAge()'>check</button>

</form>
```

Comment: It's a timezone issue.

Comment: I am in South Africa and when I ran the code it give me correct selected date. http://jsbin.com/luvolaboba/1/edit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the incorrect date is due to your timezone settings. It's GMT-8.
Consider using UTC: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toutcstring.asp

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I wanted to resurrect it since this was the first result in my Google query and the accepted answer doesn't really answer the question well.  So I'm providing a bit more information for others to stumble upon.

There are several convenience methods in the Date object which may be of help to those trying to work around this little JavaScript quirk.

It seems to me that there is no way to change a Date object timezone offset programmatically, and it must be done using String manipulation, which is truly undesirable, but there is no other way.  **The Date object constructor always uses the local machine timezone when interpreting dates, and this cannot be changed.**  As such, you must understand that when you create a Date which essentially ignores the timezone, the **altered Date object will represent a different moment in time from the original Date.**  The new Date object will automatically adopt the local machine's timezone but it will use the `(year, month, date, hour, min, sec, ms)` which you designate in either the individual constructor parameters or string parameter of the Date class (of the two options below).

I found two ways to work around this and produce a correct date from a `type="date"` input field.  Please use the one you feel is more effective or appropriate for your solution.  Personally, I prefer using *OPTION B* since it is more programatic than string manipulation and probably a bit more reliable as such.  It's also a bit simpler.

**OPTION A: UTC date string manipulation**

`getUTCDate` - returns the day of the month (from 1 to 31) of the date object, according to universal time.  The UTC methods calculate their date assuming that the date object is of local time and date.

`getUTCString` - converts a Date object to a string, according to universal time.

**NOTE: The Date constructor reverts back to local timezone.**  Therefore, you cannot build a new Date with the `getUTCString()` value and expect to get the correct date from the input field.

You can solve this issue by using `getUTCDate()` and calling `dateObject.setDate(dateObject.getUTCDate());`, which corrects only the date portion of the object, so you will need to correct the month and year as well using `dateObject.setMonth(dateObject.getUTCMonth());` and `dateObject.setFullYear(dateObject.getUTCFullYear());` respectively.  Or you can remove everything after the `"GMT"` portion of the `getUTCString()` value, which will give you a string without a timezone designation.  You can then use the string to create a new Date object, which will default to the client's timezone.

```
//convert to UTC to avoid "date minus one" issues where the supplied date is interpreted incorrectly as
//the previous date.
date = new Date(document.getElementById('date').value);
console.log("original date: " + date.toString());
console.log("UTC date string: " + date.toUTCString());
//produces local machine timezone, and therefore incorrect date value
date = new Date(date.toUTCString());
console.log("UTC date string Date constructor: " + date.toString());
utcDate = new Date(utcString.substr(0, utcString.indexOf("GMT")));
console.log("UTC date string Date constructor (without 'GMT*'): " + utcDate.toString());
console.log("UTC date number: " + date.getUTCDate());
date.setDate(date.getUTCDate());
date.setMonth(date.getUTCMonth());
date.setFullYear(date.getUTCFullYear());
console.log("UTC modified date: " + date.toString());
```

Output:

```
original date: Fri Jan 29 2021 23:16:11 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
UTC date string: Sat, 30 Jan 2021 05:16:11 GMT
UTC date string Date constructor: Fri Jan 29 2021 23:16:11 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
UTC date string Date constructor (without 'GMT*'): Sat Jan 30 2021 23:16:11 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
UTC date number: 30
UTC modified date: Sat Jan 30 2021 23:16:11 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
```

**OPTION B: provide all UTC parameters to Date constructor**
(see also: [Create a Date with a set timezone without using a string representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439630/create-a-date-with-a-set-timezone-without-using-a-string-representation))

example:

```
date = new Date(document.getElementById('date').value);
console.log("original date: " + date.toString());
date = new Date(
    date.getUTCFullYear(),
    date.getUTCMonth(),
    date.getUTCDate(),
    date.getUTCHours(),
    date.getUTCMinutes(),
    date.getUTCSeconds(),
    date.getUTCMilliseconds());
console.log("Date with UTC parameters: " + date.toString());
```

Output:

```
original date: Fri Jan 29 2021 23:04:03 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
Date with UTC parameters: Sat Jan 30 2021 07:04:03 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```